# Segmentation fault: Listas ligadas em C

Tags: c

Estou aqui a brincar um bocadinho com C e deparei-me que na segunda inserção que faço através da consola que a `lista` perde o primeiro apontador(ponteiro) criado na primeira inserção criando um

> Segmentation fault; core dumped;

Alguém sabe o motivo?

Tenho uma estrutura assim:

```
typedef struct livro 
{
    char *nome;
    int numLivros;
    struct livro *next;        
} Livro;
```

Função de alocar um livro:

```
Livro* alocaLivro( char *nome, int num) 
{
    Livro *novo     = (Livro *) malloc(sizeof(Livro));
    char *novo_nome = (char *)  malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_NOME_LIVRO);
    strcpy(novo_nome, nome);

    novo->nome      = novo_nome;
    novo->numLivros = num;
    novo->next = NULL;

    return novo;
}
```

Função de inserir livro na lista:

```
int insertLivroCauda(Livro **lista, char *nome , int num) 
{
    Livro *novo = alocaLivro(nome, num);
    if (!novo)
        return 0;

    if(*lista == NULL)
    {
        (*lista) = novo;
    }
    else
    {
        Livro *aux = (*lista);
        while (aux->next != NULL) 
        {
            aux = aux->next;
        }
        aux->next = novo;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Main:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    Livro *lista = NULL;
    char opt;
    char *my_string;

    printf("1 - Insirir novo livro\n");
    printf("2 - Remover último livro\n");

    while (scanf("%s",&opt))
    {   
        switch(opt)
        {
            case '1':
                printf("Insirir nome livro:\n");

                my_string = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char) * MAX_NOME_LIVRO );

                scanf("%s",my_string);

                insertLivroCauda(&lista, my_string, sizeof(my_string));

                break;

            default:
                return (EXIT_SUCCESS);    
        }
        printf("1 - Insirir novo livro\n");
        printf("2 - Remover último livro\n");
    }
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode não ser a causa do seu problema, mas já é um problema bem grave:

Você tem:

```
char opt;
scanf("%s", &opt);
```

O scanf está lendo uma string de tamanho **ilimitado** que será posta na **array** `opt`. Se for uma string vazia, então será composta de uma array com apenas o terminador nulo, nesse caso funciona e `opt=0`. Mas se for entrar com qualquer outra coisa, como `"1"`, já precisa de dois `char`. A função `scanf` vai cegamente escrever memória além da variável. Chega-se então ao mundo do *Undefined Behavior* e não há mais o que analisar.

Correção:

```
scanf("%c", &opt);  // leia apenas um char
```

Comment: Realmente o problema estava na leitura e não nos apontadores. Criei uma função para leitura que resolveu o problema.

Answer (score 0):

Como não entendi muito bem o que você estava tentando fazer eu tentei seguir uma lógica de que na função de inserir livro você precisava passar a Lista, o nome do livro, e o tamanho dele... então eu dei uma mexida no `main` pode ser que ajude em alguma coisa no código.
sua função de inserir livro esta recebendo como parâmetro um ponteiro para ponteiro de Livro, e você ta passando ele Nulo, bem não entendi direito e não mexi.

```
int main() 
{
    //Livro *lista = NULL; /// ???
    int opcao;
    char *CleanBuffer;
    char *Nomelivro;
    char tmdLivro;

    do   
    {   
        printf("1 - Insirir novo livro\n");
        printf("2 - Remover último livro\n");
        printf("3 - Encerrar Aplicacao \n");

        scanf("%d", &opcao);
        scanf("%c", &CleanBuffer); 

        switch(opcao)     
        {
            case 1:
                printf("Insira o nome do livro: ");
                gets(Nomelivro);
                tmdLivro = strlen(Nomelivro);          
                insertLivroCauda(//????, &Nomelivro, tmdLivro);

                break;
               ///End Case.

            default:
                return 0;   
        }
    }while (opcao != 3);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Eu começo com um ponteiro `lista` nulo e passo a referencia desse ponteiro. Depois no inserir livro é que verifico se ele for nulo o novo livro a inserir passa a ser o ponteiro `lista` (`(*lista) = novo;`)

Comment: amigo, seria bacana então você definir uma macro para esta lista com um valor não?
ele ja entraria com um valor definido por você na hora da verificação, ae é só comparar.

Comment: O problema não estava na função de inserir, está na leitura que não estava a funcionar. Acabei mesmo agora de resolver o problema, em vez de usar `gets` estou a usar uma função feita por mim de leitura de carateres.

Comment: Ótimo! quem bom então que resolveu :P

Comment: Mas o `do while` e o `CleanBuffer` ajudam bastante nessa questão.

Comment: Ah e o `gets` está obsoleta, não é mais usada.