# Como ler do stdin em C?

Tags: c, console, entrada-de-dados

Como devo ler **carateres**, **dígitos** e **strings** do stdin em C?

- getchar;
- fgetc;
- fgets;
- getc;
- scanf;

Estou aqui a tentar ler da consola e há sempre algum problema com a leitura da mesma. Já experimentei essas formas todas e há sempre qualquer problema. Cada vez que pesquiso sobre o assunto ainda fico mais na dúvida.

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42916/segmentation-fault-listas-ligadas-em-c

Comment: Cada um tem a sua caracteristica,no caso do `scanf` você pode usar para tudo, pra poder ler um `char` por exemplo vc usa `scanf("%c",&c);`, assim você consegue ler 1 char não importa o que for[número, letra, pontos,dígitos]. Lembrando que se digitar mais de um `char`ele vai ficar no buffer, pra não ocorrer problemas use alguma função para limpar o buffer [`__fpurge()`,`fflush()`] antes de cada `scanf()`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Depende do propósito, se quer ler um caractere, uma sequência ou quer um formato específico. Algumas hoje depende mais de gosto.

## `getchar()`

Lê apenas um caractere, nada mais que isto. Não importa o que. Normalmente usado quando você quer controlar a entrada de dados da maneira que bem entender. Pode ser usada para compor funções de leitura de dados de forma mais complexa.

## `fgetc()`, `getc()`

Só faria sentido em compará-las para ler o `stdin` se ele fosse usado como parâmetro já que estas funções leem algum *stream* a ser especificado, o *stdin* é um deles.

Portanto para ler o `stdin` acaba sendo uma questão de gosto. Em geral a pessoa padroniza usar um ou outro sempre. Muitas pessoas preferem ignorar duas destas três funções sempre. Pelo que eu percebo `fgetc()` é a mais escolhida pelo programadores mais experientes.

A primeira deve ser necessariamente uma função e a segunda pode ser implementada como uma macro. O que não faz mais diferença nas implementações atuais já que a primeira pode ser otimizada pelo compilador com *inline*.

## `fgets()`

Lê uma sequência de caracteres até encontrar um `\n` (que será obtido, por exemplo, quando for digitado um ENTER) de forma simples sem se importar com o que sejam esses caracteres, exceto o terminador. Ela especifica um tamanho máximo de caracteres que podem ser lidos, portanto será encerrado quando chegar neste limite mesmo que não encontre o terminador. O limite sempre é um caractere a menos que o especificado porque no final é incluso um caractere `NULL` para terminar a *string*.

Ele fica aguardando a entrada do `\n` pelo *buffer* do *stdin* (possivelmente vindo do teclado.

## `scanf()`

Esta é a função mais poderosa porque ela lê sequências de caracteres de acordo com um formato, fazendo assim algum filtro do que pode entrar.

Com ela você pode determinar o número máximo de caracteres digitados, se pode ser digitado qualquer caractere ou só alguns são aceitos (por exemplo, só dígitos numéricos). Enfim tem que estudar [todos os parâmetros de configuração](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf_format_string).

Importante notar também que a sequência de caracteres entrados pode ser convertida para um tipo específico, ou seja, você lê uma sequência de caracteres mas o resultado final pode ser um número (`int`, `float`, etc.).

O uso do parâmetro "%c" acaba determinado a leitura de apenas um caractere, funcionando assim como as primeiras funções.

Uma importante diferença para as demais é que o seu retorna indica o sucesso ou falha da leitura. O resultado em si é "retornado" através de uma referência para uma variável (passada por ponteiro).

Se tiver mais que um pode ter problemas com liberação de *buffer* em algumas situações. Vejo muito *bug* por causa disto. E soluções que nem sempre funcionam. Ela não é útil além de coisas muito simples.

#### Inadequação

Por ser uma função vulnerável como tantas outras em C é comum alguém usar outras funções personalizadas para fazer o mesmo. Funções de bibliotecas prontas de terceiros ou próprias costumam atender melhor necessidades reais e controlam melhor possíveis explorações de entradas mal formatadas.

E não é só questão de segurança, muita coisa pode dar errado quando usa esta função. Não estou dizendo que ela é terrível para usar, apenas que ela espera um mínimo de coerência por parte do digitador. E um programa sério não pode esperar isto, ele deve tratar as possibilidades mais extremas que alguém possa fazer.

Fora das aplicações ingênuas, de aprendizado, normalmente se usa alguma outra solução ou no máximo lê tudo como caractere e depois é feito uma conversão para um tipo através de uma algoritmo (provavelmente em função específica) fazendo uma série de validações. Quase nunca vemos aplicações sérias confiando na validação e conversão do `scanf()`.

Ainda bem que você não quis saber como usar o `gets()`. Como ele não limita o tamanho do pode receber de dados é usado para quebra de segurança. Ele tem um problema grave de [*buffer overflow*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow). Claro que qualquer solução se for mal usada também pode ter problemas. O `scanf()` pode ter o mesmo ou outros problemas se não usar com parâmetros corretos.

Ensinar do jeito mais simples parece adequado para facilitar o aprendizado. O problema é a pessoa aprende assim sem entender o todo e passa usar recursos que só servem para aprendizado em softwares que vão para produção. Felizmente muitas vezes essas pessoas acabam não passando do aprendizado usando C e não causam maiores problemas para todos.

## Conclusão

Se não se importar muito com o tratamento fino da entrada de dados o mais comum é usar mesmo o `scanf()` que dá mais possibilidades que outras opções. As demais costumam ser usadas em casos bem mais específicos, em geral quando vai fazer alguma coisa mais de baixo nível, possivelmente construir uma função de leitura mais complexa e mais adequada ao que você precisa.

Na prática quando a entrada de dados é importante e precisa de uma validação mais séria, a criação de uma função mais complexa e adequada ao problema é a melhor solução.

Também é raro existirem novas aplicações sérias para console hoje em dia. A preferência hoje é por GUI ou *web* e/ou utilização de uma API que controla a entrada de dados de forma própria.

Quando alguém vai fazer algo para console hoje em dia quase sempre é um utilitário interno que será usado por pessoas que sabem como usar corretamente um software mal validado. Os demais casos precisam de formas melhores de entrada de dados que as acima.

#### Exemplo de função para manipular entrada de dados:

```
int getUserInput(char * returnStr, int maxStringLength) {
   char    *tempStr;
   int     maxLen, totalCount = 0;
   size_t  len;
   maxLen = maxStringLength + 2;     //account for NULL and /newline
   tempStr = malloc(maxLen * sizeof(char));  //temporary holder
   do {
      fgets(tempStr, maxLen, stdin);  // get chars from input buffer
      len = strlen(tempStr);
      if (tempStr[len-1] == '\n') { // newline indicates end of string
         tempStr[len-1] = '\0';   // delete it
         len = strlen(tempStr);   // and recalc length
      }
      totalCount += (int)len;
   }
   while ((int)len > maxStringLength);  // continue to flush extras if too long
   strcpy(returnStr, tempStr);  // copy temp string into output
   free(tempStr);              // and release memory
   return totalCount;   // may be more than the number allowed
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Console/GetUserInput.c).

Retirado [dessa discussão](https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/c/code/268836/how-to-get-user-input-from-console-safely-). Este código pode ser bem melhorado.

Comment: O terminador do `fgets()` é um `'\n'`. Além disso o `fgets()` pode devovler uma string sem o terminador se não for especificado espaço suficiente.

Comment: É verdade, vou acertar isto. Obrigado.

Comment: Quando usas `fgets (buffer, size, stdin);` o programa fica parado a espera do input, ou continua?

Comment: Editado. Se não estiver esperando provavelmente tinha alguma coisa no *buffer* que provoca a continuidade. Todas estas funções esperam vir alguma coisa do *buffer*. O que muitos não entendem é que o *buffer* pode não estar limpo.

Comment: +1 É por estas respostas que eu adoro pertencer a comunidade do SOpt.

Comment: Ainda vou tentar melhorar algumas coisa + tarde.

Comment: @bigown, se estou a entender bem o teu exemplo, `getUserInput(s,8)`, perante a entrada "`1234567890`", vai devolve 10 e preenche `s` com "90". era este o comportamento pretendido?