# Programa não lê scanf

Tags: c

Estou fazendo um trabalho de escola, fazer um blackjack (21) em C. Em certa parte do programa, eu criei um while (enquanto a opção for sim) para mostrar as cartas, a pontuação e pergunto se o usuário quer apostar de novo (sim ou não) no fim do while. Só que o compilador encerra o programa e não lê o scanf no fim do while. Se alguém puder me dizer como resolver, ficaria grato, tenho que entregar isso ainda hoje.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define max 21

int main() {
    char naipe, nome[50], op;
    char tipo[13] = {'A','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K'};
    int valor, valorb, soma=0, somab=0;
    int i,din=1000;
    int aposta, taposta=0;

    printf("Digite o seu nome:\n");
    scanf("%s",&nome);
    op='S';

    do {
    system("cls");
    printf("Você tem %d unidades\n",din);
    printf("Escolha sua aposta inicial, %s:\n",nome);
    printf("Digite 1 para 10 unidades\n");
    printf("Digite 2 para 20 unidades\n");
    printf("Digite 3 para 50 unidades\n");
    scanf("%d",&aposta);
    } while (aposta<1 || aposta>3);
    switch (aposta) {
    case 1:
        taposta+=10;
        break;
    case 2:
        taposta+=20;
        break;
    case 3:
        taposta+=50;
        break;
    }


    while ((op=='s') || (op=='S')) {

        srand(time(NULL));
        i=rand()%12+1;
        if ((i==11) || (i==12) || (i==13))
            valor=10;
        else if (i==1)
            valor=1;
        else
            valor=i;
        naipe=rand()%3+3;
        soma=(soma+valor);

        printf("_________\n");
        printf("|%c      |\n",naipe);
        printf("|       |\n");
        printf("|   %c   |\n",tipo[i]);
        printf("|       |\n");
        printf("|      %c|\n",naipe);
        printf("\---------\n");

        i=rand()%12+1;
        if ((i==11) || (i==12) || (i==13))
            valorb=10;
        else if (i==1)
            valorb=1;
        else
            valorb=(i+1);
        naipe=rand()%3+3;
        somab=(somab+valorb);

        printf("_________\n");
        printf("|%c      |\n",naipe);
        printf("|       |\n");
        printf("|   %c   |\n",tipo[i]);
        printf("|       |\n");
        printf("|      %c|\n",naipe);
        printf("\---------\n");
        printf("\n");
        printf("Você marcou %d pontos e tem um total de %d pontos.\n",valor,soma);
        printf("O computador marcou %d pontos e tem um total de %d pontos.\n",valorb,somab);
        printf("\n");
        printf("Deseja fazer a jogada? [S/N]\n");
        scanf("%c",&op);
    }
}
```

Comment: E onde está o código?

Comment: Vacilo, tinha esquecido. Já atualizei com o código

Comment: Provavelmente ele está consumindo a resposta da pergunta anterior no scanf, por isso ele não para nunca...

Comment: Este programa nem compila, ele tem vários erros.

Comment: Ele compila sim, está compilando aqui no codeblocks.

Comment: É que você deixa *warnings* desligados. Pra mim *warning* é erro. *Warning* deixa compilar mas vai dar algo errado quando for executar. Então não faz sentido aceitar que *warnings* existam. Eu só compilo com a opção deles bloquearem a compilação. Todo programador profissional faz isto. Seu código não executa como você espera.

Comment: Aqui também não compila. Warnig em C é erro mesmo.

Comment: Ninguém aqui apontou que NÃO se deve usar scanf não é considerado seguro e não deve ser usado para receber input do usuário. Deram o peixe mastigado mas ninguém aqui apontou o porque que o código não funciona. Você não está  consumindo o buffer do stdin. Outra o fflush só pode ser usado no stdout, o uso do fflush(stdin) é uma violação. Desapontado com o SO pt.

Comment: @Vitim.us eu referi isso na minha resposta.

Answer (score 11):

Encontrei vários erros nesse código:

- falta-lhe o `#include <time.h>`;
- tem carateres de escape `\` no meio do `printf`;
- não pode usar o '10' ali no array visto que '10' são 2 caracteres;

**Tome cuidado com a forma de ler carateres do `stdin` como pode ver [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42981/como-ler-do-stdin-em-c).**

Depois adicionei a linha [`while ( getchar() != '\n' );`](http://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush2.html) para ler todos os carateres que estão no `stdin`.

Aqui está ele a funcionar **sem *warnings***:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h> 
#define max 21

int main() {
    char naipe, nome[50], op;
    char tipo[13] = {'A','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','T','J','Q','K'};
    int valor, valorb, soma=0, somab=0;
    int i,din=1000;
    int aposta, taposta=0;

    printf("Digite o seu nome:\n");
    scanf("%s",nome);
    op='S';

    do {
    system("cls");
    printf("Você tem %d unidades\n",din);
    printf("Escolha sua aposta inicial, %s:\n",nome);
    printf("Digite 1 para 10 unidades\n");
    printf("Digite 2 para 20 unidades\n");
    printf("Digite 3 para 50 unidades\n");
    scanf("%d",&aposta);
    } while (aposta<1 || aposta>3);
    switch (aposta) {
    case 1:
        taposta+=10;
        break;
    case 2:
        taposta+=20;
        break;
    case 3:
        taposta+=50;
        break;
    }


    while ((op=='s') || (op=='S')) {

        srand(time(NULL));
        i=rand()%12+1;
        if ((i==10) || (i==11) || (i==12) || (i==13))
            valor=10;
        else if (i==1)
            valor=1;
        else
            valor=i;
        naipe=rand()%3+3;
        soma=(soma+valor);

        printf("_________\n");
        printf("|%c      |\n",naipe);
        printf("|       |\n");
        printf("|   %c   |\n",tipo[i]);
        printf("|       |\n");
        printf("|      %c|\n",naipe);
        printf("---------\n");

        i=rand()%12+1;
        if ((i==10) || (i==11) || (i==12) || (i==13))
            valorb=10;
        else if (i==1)
            valorb=1;
        else
            valorb=(i+1);
        naipe=rand()%3+3;
        somab=(somab+valorb);

        printf("_________\n");
        printf("|%c      |\n",naipe);
        printf("|       |\n");
        printf("|   %c   |\n",tipo[i]);
        printf("|       |\n");
        printf("|      %c|\n",naipe);
        printf("---------\n");
        printf("\n");
        printf("Você marcou %d pontos e tem um total de %d pontos.\n",valor,soma);
        printf("O computador marcou %d pontos e tem um total de %d pontos.\n",valorb,somab);
        printf("\n");
        printf("Deseja fazer a jogada? [S/N]\n");

        while ( getchar() != '\n' );

        scanf("%c",&op);

        printf("Selecionou S/N: %c\n", op);
    }
}
```

Pode ver [aqui o exemplo](http://ideone.com/tlcgqJ)

Answer (score 6):

dê um espaço entre a aspa " e o símbolo % em:

```
scanf("%s",&nome);
scanf("%d",&aposta);    
scanf("%c",&op);
```

ficando assim:

```
scanf(" %s",&nome);
scanf(" %d",&aposta);    
scanf(" %c",&op);
```

Isso é suficiente para o `scanf()` entender que é uma nova entrada.

Você pode pesquisar também sobre a função `fflush(stdin)` para realizar a limpeza do Buffer do teclado e assim evitar que esse tipo de problema ocorra.

Comment: Nossa, só isso? Funcionou perfeitamente, valeu cara!

Comment: Gostaria de saber quem negativou a resposta sendo que o próprio autor da pergunta usufruiu dela? Acho que outras respostas podem adicionar um embasamento técnico para ser aplicado em nível profissional, e devem ser votadas positivamente para um bom desenvolvimento da comunidade, mas agora negativar a resposta que atendeu o propósito de quem perguntou já achei demais! Deixo aqui o meu desabafo!

Comment: Na Verdade Não Sei Nem Como Resolveu Para Ele Mas, Eu Votei Positivamente Na Sua Resposta, Acho Sacanagem Dar Deslike Independente Da Situação Não Importa, Mesmo Que Eu Tenho Explicado Melhor Na Minha Resposta Lá Em Cima É Sacanagem, Ou Eu Dou Like Ou Eu Deixo Pra Lá.

Comment: @dil_oliveira eu fui um dos que negativei. Devia ter deixado a explicação mas não deixei. O fflush só pode ser utilizado com stdout, o uso com stdin tem comportamento indefinido.

Answer (score 3):

Na verdade o problema está no primeiro e segundo scanf, quando você aperta o ENTER lá no primeiro scanf a string é lida e mandada para variável mas o '\n'(ENTER) fica no Buffer (A string também, mas ignore esse parênteses).
Outras coisas erradas: a biblioteca `time.h` não está incluída; para se reproduzir essa barra \ no printf você tem que digitar \\ invés de simplesmente \ e a questão do '10' (2 caracteres) em um espaço na array de char.

No segundo scanf você não tem esse problema porque você está lendo um inteiro, só que no segundo scanf outro '\n' fica no Buffer afinal você aperta ENTER para informar o inteiro.

No terceiro que é o último quando você coloca `scanf("%c",&op);` ele lê o '\n' que já está no Buffer, por isso ele não para.

**Solução:**

Faça assim, sempre que você usar o scanf use `scanf("%SeuTipo%*c", &Variável)` sempre coloque %*c que ai ele vai ler o que o usuário informar e vai descartar o '\n' que é um caractere portanto %*c resolve.

**Problema**

Supondo que o usuário informe invez de 'S' informe 'SS' ai ele iria ler 'S' e descartar o outro 'S' e o '\n' continuaria no Buffer.

**Outras Soluções**

Normalmente pra evitar dados errados você cria uma string e lê tudo que o usuário informar e coloca nela e depois faz as validações tipo com um **regex** que é simples de trabalhar, poderia usar também **fgets(que é o mais recomendado)** ou uma validação tipo essa:

Por exemplo você precisa que o usuário informe apenas inteiros

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> //Para usar strlen()

int main(){
    char string[100];
    int a = 0, i = 0;


    printf("Informe um inteiro: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]s", &string); //Esse [^\n] Faz Ele Ler Tudo Menos O '\n'
    getchar(); // Usamos O scanf, Agora Em Baixo Dele Um getchar() Para Pegar O '\n' E Descartá-lo

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++){
        if (string[i] < '0' || string[i] > '9'){ //Ocasionaria Em Um Loop Infinito Se O Usuário Não Informar Correto.
            i = -1;
            printf("\nInforme Novamente: ");
            scanf("%[^\n]s", &string);
            getchar();
        }
    }

    // Saiu Do Loop Agora Sim O Valor De string Está correto Agora Só Converter string Em Inteiro E Colocar Em (a) Que É A Nossa Variável Do Tipo Inteiro.

    a = atoi(string); //atoi = Char To Integer
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```