# Programa pula scanf

Tags: c

Meu programa pula o terceiro Scanf, já tentei de várias formas fazer funcionar mas não consegui, parece ser algum problema de alocação de memória, mas não tenho certeza, alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int impres();

int main()
{
        int x, c, i, a;
        float matriculas[500];
        scanf (" %d", &x);
        for (c=0; c!=x; c++)
        {
                for (i=0; i<2; i++)
                {
                        scanf (" %f", &matriculas[c]);
                }
                i=0;
        }

        //impressão:

        scanf (" %d", &a);
        for (c=0; c<500; c++)
        {
                if (a==matriculas[c])
                {
                        printf ("achou mizeravi");
                        break;
                }
        }
        retrun 0;
}
```

Comment: pula o terceiro scanf quando você entra com que valor para a variável x?

Comment: ou melhor, vc quer dizer com terceiro scanf, a terceira vez que o programa espera uma entrada de valor ou o scanf que preenche a variável a, que é o terceiro escrito no código?

Comment: o scanf que preenche a variável a, o terceiro no código, o programa simplesmente finaliza nem espera uma entrada.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Programa não lê scanf](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43802/programa-n%c3%a3o-l%c3%aa-scanf)

Comment: Outra [Scanf não está parando em repetição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/109966/5878)

Answer (score 2):

Boa tarde Marlon,

Seu código apresenta alguns problemas.

- **Primeiro problema: Falta de organização e clareza**

Pra você que está construindo o programa é muito claro o que ele deve fazer, mas pra quem está de fora não. O que armazena a variável "x"? e a "c"? Esses nomes não dizem nada pra outras pessoas que leem seu código, então o primeiro conselho que posso lhe dar é: organize seu código da forma mais clara possível, é uma ótima prática.

- **Segundo problema: *for***

Não pude deixar de notar que o seu código está rodando for em cima de for desnecessariamente, além de estar aplicando de forma muito confusa.

```
 for(c=0; c!=x; c++){
       for (i=0; i<2; i++){

       scanf("%f", &matriculas[c]);

      }
       i=0;
  }
```

Nesse trecho, toda vez que o *for* de cima acontecer, você vai executar o segundo *for* 
para salvar os valores, porém ele pede duas entradas, então a segunda irá sobrescrever a primeira. (Pelo menos é o que consegui entende, está bastante confuso)

Já que a necessidade é apenas salvar o número de matrícula respeitando a quantidade de alunos matriculados que você pediu, porque não aplicar **UM** simples *for*?

```
for(i=0; i<qtdAlunos; i++){
    scanf("%f", &matriculas[i]);             
  }
```

- **Terceiro problema: Tipos de dados diferentes**

Sua variável que salva a matrícula buscada é um *integer*, já o vetor que salva os números de matrículas é do tipo *float*. Não vejo muito sentido em por um número de matrícula como *float*, Mas vamos supor que seja um necessidade do seu código.

Se a sua matrícula for "12345.0000" e você procurar por "12345", não vai dar *match*.

Então outro reparo seria por as variáveis do mesmo tipo, no caso, *float*.

**Código final:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define QTD_MATRICULAS_MAX 500

int main(){

    int i, qtdAlunos;
    float matriculas[QTD_MATRICULAS_MAX], matriculaProcurada;

    scanf("%d", &qtdAlunos);

    for(i=0; i<qtdAlunos; i++){

    scanf("%f", &matriculas[i]);

    }

    scanf("%f", &matriculaProcurada);

    for (i=0; i<qtdAlunos; i++){

            if(matriculaProcurada == matriculas[i]){

            printf ("Matricula encontrada: %1.f", matriculas[i]);
            break;

      }else{

          printf("Matricula não encontrada!");
          break;
      }
   }
    return 0;
}
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Abraços e bons estudos!