# Como testar a condição em um vetor?

Tags: c, array, string

Tenho que fazer um programa que leia um texto, onde seja substituída cada primeira letra de cada palavra do texto por um caractere (*). Não consigo compilar corretamente, acredito que o problema está na minha condição (`if`).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 500

int main()
{
char text [MAX+1];
int i;

printf("Informe o texto (tamanho maximo %d caracteres:", MAX);
fflush(stdin);
gets(text);

for (i=0; i<=MAX; i++) {
if(' text[i]'==text[i]);
text[i]=' *';

}
printf(" O texto final e %s\n", text);

}
```

Comment: O que é cada primeira letra? Primeira letra de uma palavra?

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` só está correcto para as bibliotecas da Microsoft (para outras bibliotecas é Comportamento Não Definido); `gets()` é impossível de usar com segurança. Sugiro que revejas o teu programa para não usar estas construções.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 4):

Se precisas colocar * na primeira posição de cada palavra de uma string lida da entrada tente assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 500

int main()
{
    char text [MAX + 1];
    int i;
    printf("Informe o texto (tamanho maximo %d caracteres:", MAX);
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(text);

    for(i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        if((text[i - 1] == ' ') || ((i == 0) && (text[i] != ' ')))
            text[i] = ' *';
    }
    printf("O texto final e %s\n", text);

}
```

Faltava a incluir `stdio.h` para usar o `printf`.

Comment: Não necessariamente se resume a primeira posição, mas a cada espaço do texto, deve ser adicionado um caractere. EX.: *ma *alavra  * *iferente *e *m *exto.

Comment: Como faço para a primeira letra da primeira palavra também ser substituída?

Comment: @DaviAragao se você digitar espaço e  um nome qualquer o seu algoritmo já não vai ser valido.

Comment: @Gabriel Rodrigues você tinha razão obrigado por me alertar. Está corrigido.

Answer (score 4):

Tem alguns erros, inclusive ele nem compila:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 500

int main() {
    char text [MAX + 1];
    printf("Informe o texto (tamanho maximo %d caracteres:", MAX);
    fgets(text, sizeof(text), stdin);
    text[0] = '*';
    for (int i = 0; i <= MAX; i++) if (text[i] == ' ') text[i + 1] = '*';
    printf("\nO texto final e %s\n", text);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/KzazDN). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/yuyphbfo-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/ChangeChar.c).

Dei uma organizada no código e troquei a função de leitura porque a usada é obsoleta e insegura. Dá para melhorar mas acho que resolve o intuito.

O uso do `gets` não deve ser usado em nenhum programa por nenhum programador. Tanto que os [compiladores mais novos (nem tão novos assim) geram erro quando usa esta função](http://ideone.com/6nJt5C) e não deixam compilar.

Tem uma [pergunta aqui que fala disto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42981/101).

[Tem outra no SO em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/221800).

Comment: Seu programa bigown é bom, atende a necessidade, mas estou aprendendo  e meu professor não aceita que façamos uso de métodos ainda não aprendidos.

Comment: Qual método não foi aprendido?

Comment: Essas funções fgets, sizeof. Até se você tiver uma indicação de bibliografia, site  para eu pesquisar agradeço!

Comment: Então troque de professor :) O `sizeof` dá para mudar pelo `MAX`. O `fgets` não é uma opção. Não é um gosto meu. Ninguém deve usar `gets` em programa algum. Estão ensinando você fazer coisas erradas. Eu questionaria o curso que está fazendo. De que vale aprender fazer errado?

Comment: Mostre iniciativa, faça do jeito certo, mostre pro seu professor e colegas de classe que pesquisou e achou um jeito melhor de fazer. Coloquei mais informações na resposta que pode te respaldar para usar a função. Mas por favor aprenda fazer certo. Odeio ver pessoas aprendendo errado. De qualquer forma mesmo que ainda não tenha achado a minha solução melhor, você pode votar nela se achou que ela pelo menos é boa. Você pode votar em qualquer coisa no site. Veja o [tour].

Comment: Pode deixar farei o possível.

Comment: E a outra solução não faz o que você quer. Agora que vi que você tirou a aceitação, deve ter visto que tem erro nela.

Answer (score 2):

Engraçado, o seu código compilou normalmente, a unica coisa que tive que adicionar para sobrescrever todas as primeiras letras com `*` foi um if verificando se a primeira posição é diferente de vazia, assim quando o usuario digitar a primeira letra com espaço não vai dar problema.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 500

int main(){
    char text [MAX + 1];
    int i;
    printf("Informe o texto (tamanho maximo %d caracteres:", MAX);
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(text);

    if(text[0] != ' '){
       text[0] = ' *';
    }

    for(i = 0; i < MAX; i++){
        if(text[i] == ' '){
        text[i + 1] = ' *';
    }
}

    printf(" O texto final e %s\n", text);

}
```

Teste:

`Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis.`

Resultado:

`*ussum *psum *acilds, *idis *itro *bertis.`

Comment: Ele editou a pergunta colocando o código "certo". Voltei ao original.

Answer (score 1):

O teu problema maior é usar "caracteres" com mais de um símbolo.

`' text[i]'` tem 8 símbolos; `' *'` tem 2 símbolos.

Cada caracter deve ser apenas 1 símbolo.

```
if (' ' == text[i]) /* ... */;
text[i] = '*';
```

Como outros utilizadores notaram, o teu código tem outros problemas graves.