# Programa para trocar um caractere por asterisco numa string

Tags: string, codeblocks

Olá!  Preciso fazer um programa que leia um texto (string) digitado pelo usuário com no máximo 500 caracteres, e imprima esse texto substituindo a primeira letra de cada palavra por um asterisco '*'.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Olá Viviana, pode você não coloca o código que produziu até agora e nós vamos te orientando a fim de que você construa o programa e aprenda com ele, que imagino que seja o objetivo desse seu programa certo?

Comment: Isso deve ser feito com a linguagem `C` ou `C++`?

Comment: @viviana, esta pergunta parece ser duplicada, há dois tinhas atrás respondi uma com este mesmo objetivo. de uma olhada:http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/88015/como-testar-a-condi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-um-vetor

Comment: Muito obrigada, Gabriel!! Era isso mesmo que precisava! Não tinha visto que essa pergunta já havia sido feita.

Comment: É da mesma turma ;)

Answer (score 1):

Supondo que esteja usando C

```
void subs(char *str)
{
   str[0] = '*';
   int size = strlen(str);
   for(int i = 1; i < size; i++)
      if(str[i - 1] == ' ')
         str[i] = '*'
}

// Dentro da main vc le normal e chama a funcao
subs(string);
```