# Scanf não está parando em repetição

Tags: c, c++, scanf

Tenho um *loop* `while` que só terminará ao ser digitado o valor 0 (zero). Tenho uma variável que irá receber uma opção de comando. Dentro do *loop* eu possuo um `switch` case onde:

- 0) sai do programa (retorna para o while e finaliza);
- 1) solicita para que seja escrito uma letra;
- 2) mostra a letra escrita.

Bom, o problema esta na verdade no `case 1`. Segue o código feito:

arquivo: teste_while_e_switch.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int op=-1;
  char letra=' ';

  while(op!=0){
      printf("\n0) sair\
      \n1) digite uma letra\
      \n2) mostre a letra\
      \nOp: ");
      scanf("%d", &op);

      switch(op){
          case 0: { break; }
          case 1: { printf("letra: "); scanf("%c", &letra); break; }
          default:{ printf("opcao invalida.\n"); break; }
      }
  }
  printf("fim");
  return 0;
}
```

Ao rodar o programa o mesmo se comporta da seguinte forma:

```
0) sair
1) digite uma letra
2) mostre a letra
Op: 1
letra:
0) sair
1) digite uma letra
2) mostre a letra
Op:
```

Até onde meu entendimento se estende, o *loop* deveria mostrar a mensagem de `op`, aguardar até que eu digitasse uma letra e só então dar seguimento ao código mostrando novamente o menu.

Comment: Este é o velho problema do `scanf`. Não dá para usá-lo impunemente sem ter problemas de *buffer*.

Comment: @bigown saberia me explicar melhor a este respeito? E se possível uma forma de resolver isto.

Na verdade eu consigo digitar a letra e ele retorna quando eu acesso a opção 2, no entanto o loop segue sem esperar eu digitar, de forma que parece que eu estou digitando uma nova opção e não a letra que eu gostaria.

Comment: Removi meus comentários, pois eu não havia visto o problema de primeira. É exatamente isso que o @bigown falou, problema com o scanf. Provavelmente ele vai postar uma resposta.

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42981/101

Comment: Primeiramente gostaria de agradecer a lvcs e a bigown pois foram os que foram capazes de me ajudar e a entender o problema. Para quem estiver com um problema semelhante ao meu: Apenas adicionando um espaço antes da formatação do scanf foi possível resolver, todas as explicações em detalhes estão nos comentários e respostas, além de outras dicas que podem ser úteis para outros casos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Resolvi responder para dar um código mais limpo e dentro dos padrões:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char op = ' ';
    char letra = ' ';
    do {
        printf("\n0) Sair\
            \n1) Digite uma letra\
            \n2) Mostre a letra\
            \nOp: ");
        scanf(" %c", &op);
        switch (op) {
            case '0':
                break;
            case '1':
                printf("\nLetra: ");
                scanf(" %c", &letra);
                break;
            case '2':
                printf("\nLetra digitada: %c", letra);
                break;
            default:
                printf("\nOpcao invalida.");
        }
    } while (op != '0');
    printf("fim");
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/KZzcHD). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/cgvwkptc-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Console/Fgets.c).

Ainda há alguma lógica ruim nele, mas para um exercício está bom.

O uso de [`fgets()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) ainda é mais recomendado que `scanf()` que pode ser usado em coisas simples assim.

Se quiser se livrar do <kbd>ENTER</kbd> pode fazer assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char op = ' ';
    char letra = ' ';
    do {
        printf("\n0) Sair\
            \n1) Digite uma letra\
            \n2) Mostre a letra\
            \nOp: ");
        op = getchar();
        switch (op) {
            case '0':
                break;
            case '1':
                printf("\nLetra: ");
                letra = getchar();
                break;
            case '2':
                printf("\nLetra digitada: %c", letra);
                break;
            default:
                printf("\nOpcao invalida.");
        }
    } while (op != '0');
    printf("fim");
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/viLKma). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/skcoalkt-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Console/Fgets2.c).

Comment: Entendi, ao adicionar o espaço no `scanf` o problema já havia sido resolvido, eu não conhecia este problema com `buffer`. Na verdade eu desenvolvi este exercicio apenas para tentar entender o que estava havendo em um outro código que estava fazendo relacionados a listas, pois o mesmo estava entrando no mesmo problema de loop e não permitia que eu digitasse a opção corretamente.

Comment: Tanto  o `scanf` com `%c` como o `getchar`  vão ter problemas com o caractere de newline, não vão?  (Ele fica no buffer e é lido na próxima operação de entrada) . Nesse caso talvez seja melhor o  `fgets` mesmo, ou scanf com `%s`.  (E para usuários querendo evitar o enter, hora de avançar para novos realms: ncurses, ou biblitoecas gráficas, ou isso combinado com linguagens de programaçãod e alto nível )

Comment: A intenção é ter apenas um caractere. De fato para coisas reais, nada disto é solução, mas pra exercício, tá bom.

Comment: @bigown os dois links para o ideone é pro exemplo usando `scanf(" %c", &op);`

Comment: @PabloTondolodeVargas ah, blz, vou ver o que dá pra fazer pra arrumar.