# Como ler string com espaço em uma estrutura de repetição?

Tags: c

Tenho que fazer um programa para ler o nome, o autor e o preço de uma quantidade n de livros(a partir de estruturas).
Fiz uma struct para os livros dessa forma :

```
typedef struct{
    char nome[100];
    char autor[100];
    float preco;
}dadoslivros;
```

e criei uma variavel dadoslivros para poder ler as informações dos diferentes livros.

```
dadoslivros livros[100];
```

porém ao tentar ler as strings nome ou autor nao consigo ler com espaços. Já tentei:

```
for (i = 0; i < qtdlivros;i++){
    scanf("%s",livros[i].nome);
    scanf("%s",livros[i].autor);
    scanf("%f",&livros[i].preco);  
}
```

mas dessa forma leio somente nomes ou autores sem espaco, caso coloque um espaco no nome oq vem depois do espaco vai para "autores" e caso coloque espaco no autor, oq vem depois do espaco vai para "preco", dai tentei dessa forma :

```
for (i = 0; i < qtdlivros;i++){
    scanf ("%[^\n],livros[i].nome);
    scanf ("%[^\n],livros[i].autor);
    scanf ("%f",&preco);
}
```

Mas dessa forma nem entra na leitura. 
Gostaria de saber o porque disso acontecer e como fazer para ler o nome e o autor com espaço.

Comment: Veja se te ajuda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177409/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42981/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/109966/101

Comment: Obrigado, mas infelizmente nenhum me ajudou pois devido as limitações do exercicio nao posso usar a biblioteca "string.h". E essa foi a unica maneira q vi de resolver o meu problema (usando fgets() )a partir dos links q me mandou

Comment: Não consigo imaginar o que uma coisa tem a ver com a outra.

Comment: A unica maneira que consegui resolver meu problema a partir dos links que me mandou foi  usando a função fgets(), que para este exercicio nao serve pois se trata de um exercicio da faculdade e nao posso usar funções como fgets ().

Comment: Ah então nem perco tempo, esses requisitos esquisitos não servem pra ensinar nada útil, a não ser que fosse ocaso de ler tudo bruto mesmo, e nem scanf poderia usar, pq o objetivo seria treinar o algoritmo de entrada de dados

Answer (score 0):

Seu problema na hora de usar os *scansets* (o nome daquelas estruturas `"%[^\n]"`) é que, como você imagina, na hora de ele pegar o primeiro item ele lê até o primeiro retorno de carro, *mas não lê o retorno de carro*. Aí, no segundo, ele tenta ler até o próximo retorno de carro e, que coincidência!, o *primeiro* caractere que ele lê é um retorno de carro. Então não põe nada na segunda variável.

O que você precisa fazer é colocar o retorno de carro depois do seu *scanset* lá na string de formato:

```
for (i = 0; i < qtdlivros; i ++) {
    scanf("%99[^\n]\n",livros[i].nome);
    scanf("%99[^\n]\n",livros[i].autor);
    scanf("%f",&livros[i].preco);
}
```

Mas, como você não vai colocar *prompts* pedindo cada valor, dá pra economizar concatenando todas as strings de formato:

```
for (i = 0; i < qtdlivros; i ++) {
    scanf(
        "%99[^\n]\n%99[^\n]\n%f",
        livros[i].nome,
        livros[i].autor,
        &livros[i].preco
    );
}
```

Note o `99` que eu pus entre o `%` e o `[`: ele é um subespecificador de comprimento máximo de leitura. Isso impede que o `scanf()` tente escrever mais de 99 caracteres no `autor` ou no `nome` (tem que guardar um caractere para o byte nulo). Esse tipo de detalhe é muito importante para evitar a classe de erros chamada *buffer overrun*, que é um tema recorrente na programação C.

Comment: Então...Fiz dessa forma mas quando executo o programa vai direto para o preço do livro, nao entra na leitura do nome nem do autor.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode resolver rapidamente seu problema consumindo todo o buffer, de maneira que os "\n" não atrapalhem nas demais leituras.

um método que funciona muito bem é esse:

```
void flush_in(){ 
int ch;
while( (ch = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && ch != '\n' ){} 
}
```

dessa maneira você poderia deixar o seu código nesse mesmo formato:

```
int main(){
char nome[100],autor[100];
float preco;

while(1){
    scanf("%[^\n]",nome);
    flush_in();
    scanf("%[^\n]",autor);
    flush_in();
    scanf ("%f",&preco);

    printf("\n%s %s %f\n",nome,autor,preco);
}

return 0;
}
```