# Tipo de dado char precisa de espaço após aspas no scanf()

Tags: c, char, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(){

  char elevador;
  int cod=0, a=0, b=0, c=0;


  while(cod == 0){
    printf("\nElevador utilizado (a/b/c)? ");
    scanf("%c", &elevador);

    switch(elevador){
      case 'a':
        a++;
        break;
      case 'b':
        b++;
        break;
      case 'c':
        c++;
        break;
      default:
        printf("opcao inválida!");
    }
  }
}
```

Por que quando utilizo o tipo de dado `char` e utilizo o `scanf()` preciso dar um espaço após a primeira aspas?

Desta forma:

> scanf(" %c", &elevador); << Espaço após "_%c"

Pois se não utilizar assim meu programa conforme código no inicio irá funcionar de forma "anormal" podem testar, irá executar desta maneira:

[image: execução]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Porque o [`scanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) trata a entrada com uma quebra de linha no final e isto pode causar problemas de *buffer*. Este espaço indica que haverá uma substituição da quebra de linha que é espúrio aí. Normalmente só dá problema quando há repetição de leitura onde a quebra de linha acaba ficando para a próxima entrada.

[Relacionado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/109980/101).

Comment: Tu manja de mais amigo, obrigado mais uma vez. O outro tópico me ajudo a entender melhor ainda.

Grato.