# Limpar buffer em C com fflush() ou __fpurge()

Tags: c, string, buffer

Estudando strings em C me deparei com a seguinte frase: "Limpar o buffer, por exemplo, nem sempre é algo desejável, e para programação mais profissional e segura não é recomendado que se use fflush por exemplo."

Por que usar a função `fflush()` para limpar o buffer após um `scanf()` não é recomendado? Qual a melhor maneira de limpar o buffer para evitar problemas como ler o caractere NEW LINE sem querer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O melhor mesmo é entender que o `scanf` é uma função escrita na década de 70 para ler tokens a partir de streams. Pode ser conveniniente para extrair inteiros, ou strings em um porgrama interativo - mas vem de uma época em que programas interativos eram *Bem* menos interativos que os de hoje. Mesmo os programas feitos para funcionar apenas da linha de comando hoje (por exemplo, o `git`) tem uma interface sofisticada comparado com o que o scanf deixa fazer.

Então uma coisa que tem que se ter em mente é que: o uso da entrada padrão em C, seja com `scanf` ou com outras funções é um paliativo enquanto se está aprendendo a programar e para pequenos exercícios. Um sistema sério e grande, mesmo que tenha seu núcleo em C "puro" deve usar uma biblioteca de interface ou framework para criar a interface - como `gobject`, ou para C++, `boost`, ou `Qt`. Possivelmente até pode ter toda a parte de interface escrita numa linguagem de alto nível, e só os loops internos, onde a "força bruta" é necessária feitos em C.

Dito isso - scanf é bem contraintuitivo para iniciantes. Ele só lê os tokens que você manda - e se sobrar coisa no stdin, sobrou coisa no stdin. E sempre vai sobrar pelo menos o `\n`, a não ser que você leia um token `%s` or último. Uma alternativa é usar o `scanf` seguido de  `fgets` que sempre lê uma string até o fim (ou só o `fgets` se você só quer uma string).

Answer (score 8):

O principal motivo é que não há uma definição clara do padrão ISO. Poucos compiladores implementam ela de uma forma que faz o que se costuma esperar dela, especialmente com `stdin` que é usado pelo `scanf()`. Ela é uma função para descarregar *streams* de saída, o contrário do que o `scanf()` faz, pelo menos de acordo com a especificação.

Se não me engano só o compilador da Microsoft, entre os mais conhecidos, dá certo. Então se decidir usá-la, tenha certeza que o código nunca precisará ser compilado em outro compilador.

É melhor seguir a [especificação e não uma implementação específica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111284/101).

O `scanf()` é para fazer algo muito simples, não deve ser usado em nada sério, todo mundo que usa C de forma real usa alguma outra biblioteca ou faz sua própria função para lidar com entrada de dados. Sempre que for fazer algo sofisticado evite esta função, mesmo em exercícios, procure outra forma quando passa da entrada muito simples. Veja mais em [Como ler do stdin em C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42981/101).

- [Documentação GCC](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html)
- [Documentação Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fflush?view=vs-2019&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 5):

Segundo esse [link - em inglês](http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?answer=1052863818&id=1043284351):

A função `fflush()`, opera apenas sobre buffers de saída e se você forçar o uso com um buffer de entrada (ex: `stdin`, utilizado pelo `scanf`), o resultando é indefinido.

[Nesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898215/how-to-clear-input-buffer-in-c) resposta no SO (em inglês), existem várias soluções, como esta (melhor):

```
int c;

while ( (c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF ) { }
```

ou esta (que conforme os comentários, não é portável):

```
fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END);
```

As outras opções na resposta, utilizando somente o looping `while`, não parecem seguras, pois dependem da entrada do caracter `'\n'` para sair do looping.