# Parâmetros da função scanf

Tags: c, c++, funções, scanf, programação-estruturada

Ao estudar a função `scanf` com um pouco mais de profundidade me surgiu uma dúvida sobre os argumentos que eu coloco antes do % ao ler uma string, ou seja `scanf("argumentos...%s",minhastring)`, nos seguintes códigos acrescento um espaço e o caractere 'J' antes do % para verificar o comportamento do scanf, ou seja a limpeza do buffer não é o que está em estudo, pois essa não é uma maneira correta de fazer tal tratamento, mas sim a utilidade de colocar caracteres antes do %:

1ª Versão do código:

```
//abrindo um arquivo para escrever o resultado do que for digitado
FILE *arq = fopen("testes.txt","w");
char str1[20], str2[20];
//lendo duas strings, o %19 limita o numero de caracteres a ser armazenado, evitando o
//overflow e o [^\n] faz com que o conteudo seja lido até encontrar uma quebra de linha,
// tornando possivel a leitura de strings com espaço
printf("Digite a primeira string: ");
scanf("%19[^\n]s", str1);
printf("Digite a segunda string: ");
scanf("%19[^\n]s", str2);
//armazenando a string formatada no arquivo: testes.txt
fprintf(arq, "Foi digitado \"%s\" e \"%s\" ", str1, str2);
//fechando o arquivo
fclose(arq);
```

Aqui estão alguns testes e respectivas saídas em um arquivo:

1º

> Digite a primeira string: Antonio
>
> Digite a segunda string:
>
> Foi digitado "Antonio" e "NÊ8˜þÿÿÿb8v¼[=v@"

Eu então alterei o código e coloquei um espaço  antes do "%" do segundo scanf e também acrescentei o caractere 'J'.

Antes da alteração:  `scanf("%19[^\n]s", str2);`

Agora `scanf(" J%19[^\n]s", str2)`

Eu não conseguia digitar a segunda string, após digitar a primeira o programa era encerrado, no proximo exemplo o espaço provavelmente está "pegando" o '\n', e o caractere 'J' está obrigando que a Segunda string comece com a letra 'J':

2ª Versão do código:

```
FILE *arq = fopen("testes.txt","w");
char str1[20], str2[20];
printf("Digite a primeira string: ");
scanf("%19[^\n]s", str1);
printf("Digite a segunda string: ");
scanf(" J%19[^\n]s", str2);
fprintf(arq, "Foi digitado \"%s\" e \"%s\" ", str1, str2);
fclose(arq);
```

Aqui estão alguns testes e respectivos outputs em um arquivo:

1º

> Digite a primeira string: Maria Eduarda
>
> Digite a segunda string: Joao Carlos
>
> Foi digitado "Maria Eduarda" e "oao Carlos"

2º

> Digite a primeira string: Maria Eduarda
>
> Digite a segunda string: Maria Joaquina
>
> Foi digitado "Maria Eduarda" e "›Þþÿÿÿb8v¼[=v@"

Constatações interessantes: O espaço do `scanf` esta resolvendo o problema do que ficou no `stdin`, o '\n' que "sobrou" da primeira entrada de dados foi ignorado. Ao colocar a letra 'J', ou qualquer outra, antes do sinal de '%' eu somente consigo ler corretamente uma string se a mesma começar com a letra informada como parâmetro, e a letra informada é ignorada pelo `scanf`, que não a armazena na variável, como no primeiro teste:

> Digite a primeira string: Maria Eduarda
>
> Digite a segunda string: Joao Carlos
>
> Foi digitado "Maria Eduarda" e "oao Carlos"

->Essa dúvida surgiu ao fazer alguns testes e "brincar" um pouco no code blocks. Acho o C uma linguagem muito interessante. E gostaria de tirar essa dúvida: O que acontece quando coloco argumentos entre as aspas e o '%' no scanf? E quando geralmente são utilizados, se são utilizados?

Comment: Eu poderia até responder, mas não sei se é o que deseja. Primeiro: funcionar não é estar certo. Segundo: `scanf()` é problemático, pra fazer uns exercícios, ok, para uso geral, melhor usar outra coisa: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/111703/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42981/101

Comment: @bigown Foi meu primeiro post aqui, cometi um erro ao não especificar melhor minha dúvida.A questão do buffer e do stdin não eram o foco da minha pergunta, mas sim parâmetros que aparecem antes do % do scanf. Não pretendo utiliza-lo dessa forma, apenas saber se eu posso e se sim porquê, se ele foi implementado para poder ser utilizado assim ou se apenas apresentará comportamento indefinido. Por exemplo ao digitar "amor", se meu scanf estiver assim: scanf("a%s", str). Pq a letra 'a' é ignorada? Pq ao digitar uma palavra que não inicie com 'a' não consigo armazenar o valor na variável? Obrigado.

Comment: acho que voce esta acessando lugares indevido da memoria isso explica esses carateres estranho

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Antes de começar, acho que você na verdade queria usar `"%19[^\n]"` ao invés de `"%19[^\n]s"`. A segunda versão na verdade quer dizer "uma string de até 19 caracteres sem ser `\n`, seguido da letra "s".

A razão para o comportamento estranho do seu primeiro programa é que o primeiro scanf não consome o `\n` da primeira linha do seu arquivo de entrada. Quando o segundo scanf tenta rodar, ele dá de cara com esse `\n` e não consegue ler o que está na segunda linha.

Aparentemente, quando o scanf usando `[` não consegue ler nada ele não modifica o buffer de string que você passa para ele. Acho que faria mais sentido se ele preenchesse o buffer com uma string vazia mas parece que esse não é o caso... De qualquer forma, dá pra sumir com aquele output exquisito se você inicializar seus buffers com um valor padrão:

```
char str1[20] = "AAAA";
char str2[20] = "BBBB";
```

Sobre o seu segundo programa, o  no início da string de formatação do segundo scanf significa "consuma zero ou mais espaços em branco". Isso inclui o `\n` da primeira linha que tinha atrapalhado a primeira versão do seu programa (e também incluiria espaços em branco no início da segunda linha).

---

Dito isso tudo, eu não recomendo usar `scanf` para ler linhas inteiras dessa forma. Como você já deve ter percebido, é bem fácil de dar um tiro no pé com o scanf nesse caso e as duas versões do seu programa tem bugs sutis (a primeira não funciona e a segunda come espaços em branco no começo da segunda linha).

Ao invés de usar o scanf recomendo usar a função `fgets` para ler uma linha inteira. Ela recebe o buffer de saída, o tamanho máximo do buffer (número máximo de caracteres mais um) e um `FILE*` de onde a entrada vai ser lida:

```
fgets(str1, 20, stdin);
fgets(str2, 20, stdin);
```

O único problema do fgets é que ele inclui o `\n` no buffer. Se você não gostar do `\n` você vai precisar de removêlo na mão.

---

Uma outra possibilidade é ler os caracteres da entrada um a um, com `getchar` ou `fgetc`. Dá mais trabalho mas permite que você tenha um controle bem fino do que você está fazendo.

---

Voltando à pergunta no final do seu post:

> O que acontece quando coloco argumentos entre as aspas e o '%' no scanf?

O primeiro argumento da função scanf (a "format string") consiste de uma sequência *diretivas*. Uma diretiva pode ser:

1. Uma sequência de espaços (espaço, tab, quebra de linha, etc)
2. Uma letra normal (sem ser `%` ou um espeço)
3. Uma especificação de conversão, começando com a letra `%`

A semântica do scanf consiste em processar as diretivas em sequência.

1. Na diretiva de espaços, o scanf consome zero ou mais espaços, parando logo antes primeiro caractere da entrada que não for um espaço ou do EOF.
2. No caso da diretiva de letra normal, o scanf tenta ler exatamente um caractere da entrada e falha se o caractere lido não for o esperado.
3. No caso das diretivas com `%`, o scanf faz algo diferente dependendo de cada caso. Geralmente vai ser ignorar espaços seguido de tentar ler alguma coisa da entrada.

Para um exemplo concreto, considere a chamada `scanf(" J%d%19[abc]", &n, buf)`. Nesse caso a format string tem 4 diretivas e o scanf vai fazer o seguinte:

1. Ignorar todos os espaços em branco no começo da entrada.
2. Ler a letra `J` da entrada (e falhar se não tinha um J para ler)
3. Ignorar espaços em branco; ler um número da entrada e armazená-lo no endereço `&n` (e falhar se não der pra ler um número)
4. Ler uma string (de no máximo 19 letras) contendo apenas as letras `a`, `b`, ou `c` e armazenar ela em `buf`. (A conversão `%[` é uma exceção e não ignora espaços em branco antes de tentar ler os dados formatados)

Comment: Obrigado por comentar, como disse pra outro usuário expliquei mal minha dúvida, por isso editei o post para ficar mais claro. Conheço a função fgets, e sempre a utilizo quando trabalho com strings, só queria mesmo saber melhor como o scanf trabalha. Tanto scanf quanto printf são funções interessantes que muitas vezes não tiramos todo potencial. Novamente obrigado.

Comment: Editei minha pergunta pra tentar esclarecer o comportamento do scanf. Para mais detalhes, recomendo ler [o manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/scanf.html)

Comment: @JJoao: Você estava certo... eram erros de digitaçao.

Comment: Muito obrigado pelos comentários, me ajudaram muito.

Comment: @LuisHenrique: não esqueça de marcar a resposta como "aceita" :)