# Como passo um array de apontadores de estruturas para uma função?

Tags: c, array, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NUM_NOTAS 5
#define TAM_NOME 20


struct Aluno{
 char nome[TAM_NOME];
 int numero;
 int notas[NUM_NOTAS];
};
void preenche(struct Aluno* lista[], int tam){
 int i;
 int j;
 for(i=0;i<tam;i++){
    printf("Nome:");
    scanf("%s",&(lista[i])->nome);
    printf("Número:");
    scanf("%d",&(lista[i])->numero);
    for(j=0;j<5;j++){
        printf("Introduza a nota %d:",j);
        scanf("%d",&(lista[j])->notas[j]);
    }
 }
}



int main(int argc, char** argv) {
 struct Aluno* lista[5];
 preenche(&lista[5],5);



 return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Gostaria de saber como é que passo `struct Aluno* lista[5];` para a função `preenche`, porque da maneira que estou a fazer a função não lê o array.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu acho que o que você que r na verdade é isso:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NUM_NOTAS 5
#define TAM_NOME 20

struct Aluno {
 char nome[TAM_NOME];
 int numero;
 int notas[NUM_NOTAS];
};

void preenche(struct Aluno lista[], int tam) {
    for (int i = 0; i < tam; i++) {
        printf("\nNome:");
        scanf("%s", lista[i].nome);
        printf("\nNúmero:");
        scanf("%d", &lista[i].numero);
        for (int j = 0; j < NUM_NOTAS; j++) {
            printf("\nIntroduza a nota %d:", j);
            scanf("%d", &lista[i].notas[j]);
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    struct Aluno lista[2];
    preenche(lista, 2);
    printf("\n----------------------");
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        printf("\nNome:");
        printf("%s", lista[i].nome);
        printf("\nNúmero:");
        printf("%d", lista[i].numero);
        for (int j = 0; j < NUM_NOTAS; j++) {
            printf("\nNota %d:", j);
            printf("%d", lista[i].notas[j]);
        }
    }
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/YylZGc). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/jguhlkfv-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Struct/PassToFunction.c).

Note que não tem porque ter esse ponteiro. E se tem, precisaria alocar memória para ele. Aí basta passar a própria variável que já é um *array* ([na verdade é um ponteiro no fim das contas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91336/101)). Dá pra simplificar fazendo assim e resolve o que precisa.

Resolvi alguns outros pequenos problemas. E mandei imprimir o resultado pra ver que está correto.

Se deseja usar um ponteiro, então use um ponteiro e não o *array*. Neste caso basicamente a mudança deve ser na declaração da variável que deve alocar memória de outra forma. Para um ponteiro para *array* precisa ter sentido nisso, o que não é o caso. Respondi com *array* porque é o que está na *tag*, e o código parece indicar que ele é importante, enquanto que o ponteiro não.

Comment: Mas o meu objectivo é passar como apontador, nesse caso o que teria que fazer?Porque a minha dúvida é trabalhar em estruturas com apontadores e gostava de perceber.

Comment: @ppfernandes Mas qual o motivo que quer passar como ponteiro? Não parece ter nenhum, o que está criando uma complicação desnecessária.

Comment: Sim eu sei mas isto é um exercício(de uma ficha) que precisa de ser feito dessa maneira mas já o consegui fazer obrigado pela ajuda.Quer que passe a minha resolução para o site?

Comment: @ppfernandes Quem pediu para fazer o exercício não está sendo razoável e está induzindo você aprender coisa errada. Eu tenho quase certeza que a solução está errada, apesar de aparentar que funciona. Funciona porque é um exercício simples que tem um uso de memória muito controlado, se for fazer a mesma coisa em outro código vai dar erros graves. Eu vivo dizendo que estar certo e funcionar são coisas bem diferentes. Para apender deve fazer o certo. Isto foi o que eu te mostrei. Além disso não tem na pergunta o requisito do exercício que deveria ter uma fundamentação para o pedido.

Answer (score 0):

Basta trocar o `preenche(&lista[5],5);` por `preenche(lista, 5);`.

Ah, acho que no seu `scanf("%d",&(lista[j])->notas[j]);` você queria na verdade `scanf("%d", &(lista[i])->notas[j]);`. Ou seja, usou `j` ao invés de `i`.

Comment: Ao colocar dessa forma, lista[5] não entra na função.Simplesmente lê lista como um e não um array.

Comment: @ppfernandes Mas não é dessa forma que eu disse que é para colocar. É para colocar apenas `lista`, e não `lista[5]` e nem `&lista[5]`.

Comment: Sim eu usei a sua maneira mas dessa maneira não passa o array.Veja o print acima devia de aparecer lista[0],lista[1],.. e não só *lista.

Comment: @ppfernandes Acho que o seu problema está no `scanf`. Veja essa pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/137262/132