# Porque estou tendo problemas com 'scanf' em C?

Tags: c, io

Olá, estou tentando fazer um cmd bem básico, mas estou tendo problemas...

Meu código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char arg[300];

    scanf("print '%s'", arg);
    printf("%s", arg);

    fgetc(stdin);
    fgetc(stdin);
    return 0;
}
```

Então fui testar:

```
entrada: print 'hello world'
saída: hello //não coloca o que eu queria
```

Mas o que eu queria era:

```
entrada: print 'hello world'
saída: hello world
```

Alguém pode me explicar o que está acontecendo?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Parâmetros da função scanf](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/137262/par%c3%a2metros-da-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-scanf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Porque o `%s` lê uma palavra. Isso significa que o espaço em branco entre o `hello` e o `world` é uma das coisas que faz ele parar de ler.

Use `%[^']s` ao invés disso. Esse `[^']` significa algo mais ou menos como "*leia enquanto não encontrar um caractere `'`*".

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/sk9Ru0)

Answer (score 4):

Acontece que `scanf` realiza a leitura da string até encontrar um espaço, assim sua saída será apenas os caracteres correspondentes antes do `scanf` encontrar um espaço, como `saida: hello`.

Para leitura de uma string que contenha espaços em branco, recomendo que você utilize o comando `fgets(var, size_var, stdin)` em C.

```
int main(void) {
    char arg[300];

    printf("print "); 
    fgets(arg, 300, stdin); //realiza a leitura de uma string com espaços
    printf("%s", arg);

    fgetc(stdin);
    fgetc(stdin);

    return 0;
}
```

Agora sua saída deverá ser `hello world`.

Espero ter ajudado.