# Dúvida no fluxo stdin da função scanf()

Tags: c, c++, char, conversão

Saudações a todos. Sou iniciante em **C** e me deparei com a seguinte dúvida referente a entrada de dados;

```c
int number1,number2;

printf("Digite o numero : ");
scanf("%d",&number1);
printf("Digite outro numero : ");
scanf("%d",&number2);
```

Nesse código se o usuário digitar números inteiros duas vezes funcionará normalmente. Porém se por descuido for digitado um caractere diferente de inteiro, em `scanf("%d",&number1);` , por exemplo, qualquer outra chamada para entrada como em `scanf("%d",&number2);` e todas as outras chamadas `scanf()` no código entram valores aleatórios, aparentemente.

Uma entrada `scanf("%c",&number1);` funciona parcialmente, ou seja, aparentemente a conversão da entrada para caracter foi realizada, mesmo que o valor não seja o mesmo que digitamos em valor inteiro e pula o `scanf()` seguinte.

Aqui na comunidade encontrei uma resposta bem próxima do que procurava mas não esse fato em especial com a função `scanf()`. [*Parâmetros da Função Scanf( )*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/137262/par%c3%a2metros-da-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-scanf)

> Então minha dúvida é, por qual motivo a inserção de um  `char`  na chamada `scanf("%d",&number1);` não causa erro e para a execução do programa?
>
> E já que não causa erro, aparentemente, por qual motivo não ocorre a chamada para a entrada de `number2` e as chamadas seguintes das `scanf()` para inserção de valores, inclusive, inserindo tais valores descohecidos ignorando totalmente os comandos solicitados?

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno, vou inclusive adotar essa boa prática, mas a [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/189633/devemos-desprezar-o-retorno-de-fun%c3%a7%c3%b5es-em-c-que-j%c3%a1-recebem-o-valor-desejado-pelo) não esclarece minha dúvida. Não me refiria a um modo de como filtrar a entrada de dados mas sim como funciona a conversão da leitura pelo teclado no `scanf()` para **provocar a inserção de tais caracteres aparentemente aleatorios** em todas as solicitações restantes do código e impedindo, inclusive, de se ler as outras variáveis.

Comment: Não é o scanf que insere os dados aleatórios. Os números são aleatórios no seu exemplo porque eles não foram inicializados, como não foram inicializados eles têm um valor aleatório que é equivalente ao estado da memória no momento em que as variáveis foram alocados no stack. Então, quando o scanf falha, ele não faz absolutamente nada e deixa as variáveis inalteradas. Se você não entendeu muita coisa do que eu disse, faz um teste: substitua `int number1,number2;` por `int number1 = 42; int number2 = 21;` e então vê quais valores essas variaveis possuem depois do scanf.

Comment: Quanto à questão do erro. A resposta indicada pela comunidade responde a sua pergunta. E, por fim, o motivo de o scanf também não conseguir ler o `number2` caso o `number1` tenha falhado é que ele como ele falhou da primeira vez, ele não limpou o buffer de entrada(stdin), então, quando ele vai tentar ler o `number2`, ele encontra o caractere que você digitou... e falha de novo. De novo, faça um teste. Depois da linha `scanf("%d",&number1);`, insira `scanf("%*s");`, execute o seu programa e você vai ver que o `number2` é lido.

Comment: Muito obrigado fiz os testes aqui e funcionou exatamente como voce disse. Era exatamente o que queria saber.