# Erro ao limpar buffer no GCC (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc, buffer

Estava assistindo um tutorial de `C`, e apareceu uma parte sobre limpeza de buffer usando as funções `fflush` e `__fpurge`. Até aí, tudo bem, mas quando eu tentei aplicar com `__fflush`, o `GCC` me retorna o seguinte erro:

```
warning: implicit declaration of function ‘__fpurge’; did you mean ‘__wur’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  __fpurge(stdin); // limpa buffer de entrada
```

E, ao tentar usar o `fflush`, não realiza a limpeza. Como proceder?

Código usando `fflush`:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
        char letra1,
             letra2;

        // uso da função getc(metodo_de_entrada)
        printf("Insira um caractere: \n");
        letra1 = getc(stdin);

        fflush(stdin); // limpa buffer de entrada

        printf("Insira outro caractere: \n");
        letra2 = getc(stdin);

        printf("Voce digitou: '%c' e '%c'\n", letra1, letra2);
        return 0;
}
```

Código usando `__fpurge`:

```
 #include<stdio.h>

int main(){
        char letra1,
             letra2;

        // uso da função getc(metodo_de_entrada)
        printf("Insira um caractere: \n");
        letra1 = getc(stdin);

        __fpurge(stdin); // limpa buffer de entrada

        printf("Insira outro caractere: \n");
        letra2 = getc(stdin);

        printf("Voce digitou: '%c' e '%c'\n", letra1, letra2);
        return 0;
}
```

Estou usando `Ubuntu 18.04` e `GCC 7.4.0`

Comment: fflush tem comportamento indefinido quando aplicado a streams de entrada (stdin). Veja questão 12.26a de http://www.faqs.org/faqs/C-faq/faq/. Veja: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/111697/limpar-buffer-em-c-com-fflush-ou-fpurge#111703

Comment: Só para que conste, no código que você mostra na pergunta não existe necessidade de limpar o buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De maneira geral não é necessário fazer "limpeza" de buffers de entrada, as funções normais de entrada/saída são suficientes para todas as necessidades.

Além disso a função `fflush` para `stdin` não é padrão, não funciona no Linux, por exemplo.

E `__fpurge` é pior ainda, como tem dois caracteres `_` no início, isto indica que é uma função interna da biblioteca C, não deve ser utilizada por programas de aplicação.

Dicas:

1. entrada de dados de campos numéricos (`%d`, `%f` etc) ignora espaços iniciais e caracteres de fim de linha (`\r` e `\n`)
2. entrada de dados de string (`%s`) ignora espaços iniciais e caracteres de fim de linha (`\r` e `\n`)
3. entrada de dados de caracter (`%c`) NÃO ignora espaços iniciais e caracteres de fim de linha (`\r` e `\n`), mas isso é contornado facilmente utilizando um formato `" %c"`, isto é, com um espaço antes do `%c`; este espaço anterior "come" todos os espaços, tabulações e fim de linha, antes de ler o próximo caractere

Answer (score 2):

Após ler o artigo que o usuário `anonimo` [deixou nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/397312/erro-ao-limpar-buffer-no-gcc-ubuntu-18-04#comment780643_397312), e de acessar [esta página](https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/dica/Limpando-a-sujeirinha-no-buffer-do-teclado/), me deparei com algumas alternativas pra efetuar a limpeza que eu precisava (e fazer o computador "esquecer" que eu apertei <kbd>ENTER</kbd> após digitar um `char`).

A primeira delas foi usando a função `scanf`, que vem como padrão na biblioteca `stdio.h`:

```
scanf(" %c", &letra2); // inserindo um "espaço" entre as primeiras aspas duplas e o '%c'
```

Outra forma que há de fazer o mesmo é inserindo um `getchar` "fantasma" (sem variável recebendo ele) após digitar algo:

```
letra1 = getc(stdin);
getchar();
```

Outra forma que existe é usando `scanf("%c%*c", &letra1);`, mas não testei essa forma, então nada posso dizer sobre sua eficácia.