# Como inserir uma String numa Pilha, com Linguagem C

Tags: c, array, stack, scanf

Estou estudando linguagem C, estou na aula de Pilhas, mas estou com uma dúvida simples (acredito)

Meu codigo funciona(da maneira que espero), se eu passar os paramentos de forma manual, como abaixo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Pilha {
    int topo;
    int * proxElemento;
};

void criaPilha (struct Pilha *p){
    p->topo = -1;
    p->proxElemento = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
}

void insereItem (struct Pilha *p, char * nome) {
    p->topo++;
    p->proxElemento[p->topo] = nome;
}

int main() {
    struct Pilha *pilhaLivros;
    criaPilha(&pilhaLivros);
    insereItem(&pilhaLivros, "Livro 1");
    insereItem(&pilhaLivros, "Livro 2");
    insereItem(&pilhaLivros, "Livro 3");
    return 0;
}
```

Quando troco o método de inserção de valores na Pilha, por um scanf ou gets(como abaixo), não dá erro na inserção propriamente dita, os dados são recebidos e inseridos pela função insereItem

```
int main() {
    char * nome;
    struct Pilha *pilhaLivros;
    criaPilha(&pilhaLivros);

    printf("Digite o livro 1: ");
    scanf("%s", nome);
    insereItem(&pilhaLivros, nome);

    return 0;
}
```

ou

```
int main() {
    char * nome;
    struct Pilha *pilhaLivros;
    criaPilha(&pilhaLivros);

    printf("Digite o livro 1: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(nome);
    insereItem(&pilhaLivros, nome);

    return 0;
}
```

Mas o conteúdo guardado em p->proxElemento[p->topo] não foi o lido pela variavel nome.

Como posso resolver esse problema?

obrigado

Comment: Há alguns problemas no seu código (como passar um endereço de um `ponteiro` ao invés de um endereço de uma `struct Pilha`). Você aparentemente cria um vetor de `int` para armazenar uma `string` em cada posição, isso não vai dar certo, faça uma matriz de `char`. Não utilize o [fflush](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/111697/limpar-buffer-em-c-com-fflush-ou-fpurge) com `stdin` como argumento.

Comment: Oi Julio, obrigado pela ajuda, entendo o que fala, mas no intuito de entender melhor meu código, gostaria(se possível) que me explicasse, pq quando mando a string direto funciona perfeito, mas quando passo a string pela variavel lida, não funciona

Answer (score 1):

Seu código que você diz funcionar não funciona, na sua máquina ele pode parecer funcionar, mas ele não faz o que você realmente quer (o código gera vários `warning` e isso significa que seu programa vai rodar de forma inconsistente).

## **Problemas**

### **Passar um endereço de um `ponteiro`**

#### **Problema**

Repare nas suas funções:

```
void criaPilha (struct Pilha *p)
void insereItem (struct Pilha *p, char * nome)
```

Ambas precisam de um endereço de uma `struct Pilha`, entretanto você está passando um endereço de um `ponteiro` do tipo `struct Pilha`. Observe:

```
struct Pilha *pilhaLivros; /* pilhaLivros eh um ponteiro */
criaPilha(&pilhaLivros) /* logo voce esta passando um endereco de um ponteiro */
```

#### **Solução**

Para resolver isso basta que `pilhaLivros` não seja declarada como ponteiro, assim:

```
struct Pilha pilhaLivros; /* agora pilhaLivros nao eh um ponteiro */
```

### **Utilizar um vetor de `int` para armazenar `string`**

#### **Problema**

Você aparentemente cria um vetor de `int` para armazenar uma `string` em cada posição, observe:

```
struct Pilha {
    int topo;
    int * proxElemento; /* aqui eh seu ponteiro que vai usar como se fosse um vetor */
};



/* aqui eh na funcao criaPilha */
p->proxElemento = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)); /* entao voce aloca memoria */



/* aqui eh na funcao insereItem */
p->proxElemento[p->topo] = nome; /* e coloca cada string em uma posicao dele */
```

Aqui temos alguns problemas.

**Utilizar um vetor de `int` para armazenar `string`**

Um `vetor` de `int` serve para armazenar várias variáveis do tipo `int`, se quer armazenar `float`, então o vetor tem que ser de `float` e essa lógica segue para qualquer tipo. Não temos algo assim:

```
string vetor[10];
```

Para criar um vetor de `string` precisamos lembrar que uma `string` já é um vetor, então um vetor de `string` é um vetor de vetores (uma matriz).

```
struct Pilha {
    int topo;
    int * proxElemento; /* isso aqui precisa ser uma matriz de char */
    char proxElemento[5][10]; /* uma matriz de char eh o que voce precisa */
};
```

A matriz acima consegue armazenar `5` `string`, onde cada uma delas não pode ultrapassar `10` de tamanho. Para criar uma matriz com alocação dinâmica precisamos de um `ponteiro` de `ponteiro`, repare:

```
struct Pilha {
    int topo;
    char **proxElemento; /* vamos usar o malloc para criar uma matriz */
};
```

**Criando uma matriz usando ponteiro de ponteiro**

No `malloc` devemos informar o tamanho de `bytes` que vamos alocar. Se quiser uma matriz que tenha 10 `string` então devemos colocar o valor 10 no malloc. Exemplo:

```
p->proxElemento = (int*) malloc(sizeof char * 10);
p->proxElemento = malloc(10); /* char vale 1 byte entao o sizeof nao eh necessario, a conversao tambem nao eh necessaria */
```

Sua função criaPilha ficaria assim:

```
void criaPilha (struct Pilha *p){
    p->topo = -1;
    p->proxElemento = malloc(10);
}
```

Agora podemos ter `10` `string` diferentes.

**Adicionando uma `string`**

Repare como você estava adicionando uma matriz:

```
void insereItem (struct Pilha *p, char * nome) {
    p->topo++;
    p->proxElemento[p->topo] = nome;
}
```

Lembre-se que não podemos atribuir diretamente uma `string`, veja:

```
a  = 10; /* valido */
b = 4.7; /* valido */
c = "teste"; /* invalido */
```

Podemos copiar uma `string` em outra usando [strcpy](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/). Então a função insere ficaria assim:

```
void insereItem (struct Pilha *p, char * nome) {
    p->topo++;
    strcpy(p->proxElemento[p->topo], nome);
    /* p->proxElemento[p->topo] = nome; */
}
```

Mas antes de fazer isso é necessário alocar quantos `bytes` nossa `string` precisa ter, dessa forma:

```
void insereItem (struct Pilha *p, char * nome) {
    p->topo++;
    p->proxElemento[p->topo] = malloc(31); /* agora voce pode adicionar um string com ate 30 de tamanho */
    strcpy(p->proxElemento[p->topo], nome);
    /* p->proxElemento[p->topo] = nome; */
}
```

O ideal é você verificar o tamanho da `string` `nome` e alocar somente o necessário (não esqueça de deixar 1 espaço a mais para o `\0`).

Com essas alterações seu código deve funcionar, você pode colocar um `scanf` que vai funcionar normalmente.

Veja seu código funcionando [aqui](https://ideone.com/DMibzp).

**OBS**

Não esqueça de utilizar o [free](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/) para liberar memória quando deletar uma `string` ou quando destruir a `pilha`.

Você pode criar uma variável do tipo `int` dentro de sua `struct` para guardar quantas `string` sua pilha pode armazenar e assim manter o controle.