# Como faço para uma string maior que o fgets dela não passe para o próximo fgets? (C)

Tags: c, string

Gente, tenho essas duas entradas de string:

```
printf("Entre com a string: ");
fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);

printf("\nEntre com o caracter a ser procurado: ");
fgets(caracter, sizeof(caracter), stdin);
```

Acontece que se eu colocar uma string maior na primeira entrada, ela acaba sendo armazenada na segunda e meu programa buga. Tem alguma forma deu controlar isso e fazer com que a primeira entrada só armazene a quantidade que estipulei?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/111702/112052

Answer (score -1):

Este problema acontece pois o `fgets` vai ler todos os caracteres que você pedir menos um, pois o último sempre será um `\0`, então se você pediu para ele coletar apenas 10 caracteres porém digitar:

Input:

```
abcdefghijklmno[enter]
```

Ele irá pegar para sua string apenas o `abcdefghi\0`.

Mas o problema acontece com o resto do input e o <kbd>enter</kbd> no final dele, pois ele acabou ficando apenas jogado no buffer do teclado (`stdin`) como um `jklmno[enter]` solto, então quando o programa achar a próxima entrada de dados que utilize o `scanf`, esse buffer já vai ser lido instantenamente e por já ter um <kbd>enter</kbd> já vai mandar esses dados para esse input

Porém como já apontado no link do hkotsubo nos comentários, uma solução bem simples muito comentada para balancear um problema gerado pela proteção de overflow do `fgets`, é usar o `fflush(stdin);` para limpar o buffer do teclado, que resolve esse problema de maneira simples, porém **não é o ideal e muito menos o seguro**, por isso muitas vezes você verá uma solução maior para resolver o problema de maneira mais segura que é o:

```
int c;
while ( (c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF ) { }
```

Esse `while` basicamente vai consumir o seu buffer até achar o <kbd>enter</kbd> e o End Of File.

Ou até mesmo essa solução que não é portável para outros sistemas:

```
fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END);
```

Todas elas funcionam parcialmente para mitigar os problemas de entrada do teclado, [se quiser ver mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42981/como-ler-do-stdin-em-c) para buscar uma solução mais segura, tambem linkado no tópico do comentário.

Comment: Não, no link que eu indiquei diz justamente o oposto: que usar `fflush(stdin)` é errado, por ser um comportamento indefinido.

Comment: Perdão, não deixei tão claro a importância dos outros métodos e o problema do fflush, imagino estar mais coeso agora