# Como evitar buffer overflow em C/C++

Tags: c, c++, segurança, memória

O programa abaixo permite a ocorrência de estouro de memória, pois é possível sobrescrever a variável zero, colocando uma valor "grande" na variável `buffer`. Como fazer um programa seguro evitando o *buffer overflow*?

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(){
    char buffer[8];
    int zero = 0;

    gets(buffer);
    puts(buffer);

    if(zero == 0){
        printf("Zero continua sendo zero");
    }else{
        printf("A variavel zero foi modificada");
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: cuidado! Não é garantido que esse programa funcione (é até estranho que funcione, na verdade). Você está assumindo uma ordem das variáveis na memória que não é garantia da linguagem. O compilador é livre para reorganizá-las.

Comment: @Kahler, obrigado!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

É até simples, basta usar uma função mais moderna que evitar o estouro, ela é o [`fgets()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42981/101), onde pode determinar o tamanho do *buffer* e a própria função se encarregará de proteger a memória. Para todos os efeitos a `gets()` é considerada insegura e obsoleta.

Aproveite e prefira o [`fputs()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fputs) também, ainda que não tenha o mesmo problema.

Se for usar C++, conforme consta na pergunta tem outras opções. Dependendo do caso um [`cin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin) pode ser mais indicado. Tem várias [funções para entrada e saída de dados](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io).

Em C++20 pode ser interessante usar outro [recurso de formatação](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).