# Diferença entre %i e %d

Tags: c, terminologia, formatação, printf

Existe alguma diferença entre `printf("%d", x);` e `printf("%i", x);`?
Eu sei que os dois retornam o mesmo resultado, tem algum tipo de convenção adotada para usar sempre o `%d`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Os especificadores de conversão `%i` e `%d` são interpretados da mesma forma pelas funções da família `fprintf()`, porém, são interpretados de forma diferente pela família de funções do `fscanf()`.

Ambos estão presentes em todos os padrões: `C89`, `C90`, `C99` e `C11`.

`%d` é usado exclusivamente com números decimais inteiros, já o `%i` é usado apenas para inteiros (independente se a base é octal, decimal ou hexadecimal).

O `%i` em um `fscanf()` é capaz de diferenciar inteiros pelos predicados, por exemplo:

> `123`: Decimal
>
> `0173`: Predicado Octal
>
> `0x7B`: Predicado Hexadecimal

Os inteiros exemplificados acima, serão todos interpretados como o decimal `123`.

Comment: C90 ? acho que deve ser C99...

Comment: Acredito que isso exista desde os primórdios da linguagem. Fiz um teste no `GCC`, e consegui compilar programas contendo o `%i` com os flags `-std=c89` e `-Wpedantic` setados, sem erros ou warnings.

Comment: Lacobus, o que o @JoséX. quis dizer é que não existe C90. Existe C99.

Comment: Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_C#C90

Comment: Manual do GCC, flag `-std=`: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html

Comment: Wikipedia: The same standard as C89 was ratified by the International Organization for Standardization as ISO/IEC 9899:1990, with only formatting changes,[1] which is sometimes referred to as C90. Therefore, the terms "C89" and "C90" refer to essentially the same language.

Comment: Wikipedia, mesmo artigo: _This standard has been withdrawn by both ANSI/INCITS and ISO/IEC_...bom, eu nunca vi ninguém referenciar esse padrão, sempre vi C89, C99, e agora C11

Answer (score 34):

Nenhuma diferença, vai produzir exatamente o mesmo resultado.

A diferença ocorre no [`scanf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) e suas variações. O `%d` só permite entrada de um número inteiro com sinal no formato decimal. O `%i` permite a entrada no formato hexadecimal ou octal.

A função do `scanf()` é receber a digitação de caracteres, sempre assim, ele não recebe números. O que ele faz é analisar esses caracteres e baseado em critérios, tentar convertê-los para números.

Portanto seu uso isoladamente é bem pouco útil. Em geral nos exercícios em C ou coisas muitos simples, que provavelmente nem deveria ser feitos em C, usa-se de forma ingênua e para esse propósito não há grande problema. É comum as pessoas terem outros meios de entradas de dados em sistemas de produção. As variações leem outras fontes de dados que tem mais controle e pode ser que o conteúdo seja garantidamente válido. [Note o que acontece quando se digita algo inválido](http://ideone.com/3RsqV0).

Quando usa-se o `%d` o padrão determina que os caracteres que sejam apenas dígitos numéricos e símbolos agregados, notadamente o sinal de negativo.

Já no `%i` é possível incluir um prefixo indicando que o formato de entrada é outro (sem prefixo é usado o decimal), aí se usar, por exemplo `0x`, as letras de `a` até `f`, não importa a caixa, são aceitas também, já que a notação hexadecimal as permite.

Claro que não é só questão de quais caracteres são aceitos, o algoritmo de conversão também é diferente para produzir o número esperado.

Lembre-se que a [entrada e saída de dados são representações numéricas e não os números em si](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/152950/101).

Para usar esse formato a variável de *buffer* deve ser um tipo inteiro qualquer.

Antes de usar o `scanf()` entenda [Como ler do stdin em C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42981/101)

[Documentação](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 19):

No `printf`, ambos são equivalentes (imprimir um inteiro na base 10). No `scanf`, o `%i` interpretará o número diferente se ele for precedido por `0x` (interpretação como hexadecimal).