# Como converter binário em decimal?

Tags: c, conversão, números-binários

Tive que fazer uma equação enorme pra converter um numero binário em decimal.

Qual é a melhor maneira de fazer uma conversão desse tipo?

Por exemplo

```
0011 1011 0101 = 949
```

Por sugestão do Jorge B., estou colocando minha tentativa de conversão, apenas para ilustração, não é preciso corrigir/levar a serio, é apenas ilustrativo, .

```
temp3 =   
    (listReport.numberBaseA*2)*(listReport.numberBaseA*2)*(listReport.numberBaseA*2)+ 
    (listReport.numberBaseB*2)*(listReport.numberBaseB*2) + 
    (listReport.numberBaseC*2) + 
    (listReport.numberBaseD) 
;
```

Bom, isso foi apenas para 4 bits, minhas conversões precisam de 24 bits, então imaginem o tamanho...

Estou estudando este codigo fornecido pelo Bacco, estou apanhando pacas!   mas estou firme e forte  estudando ele!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>

int main()
{
    char bin[100];
    int dec = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int s;
    fgets( bin, sizeof(bin), stdin);
    s = strlen( bin );
    while( s-- ) dec = dec + pow(2, i++) * (bin[s] - 48);
    printf("\nDecimal Equivalent of Binary Number: \t %d\n", dec);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Mas sabes como converter à mão? Tentaste alguma coisa?

Comment: sim. no momento eu escrevi um funcao cheia de variaveis! rsrsr  ficou horrivel!  e grande, mas nao erra o valor!   Porem preciso aprender o jeito certo!

Comment: Ah isso é muito bom, não queres acrescentar a tua função para melhorar o conteúdo da pergunta? Assim até te podem ajudar no que poderás ter feito mal, nós aqui fazemos revisão de código ;)

Comment: acrescentei! não vale dar rizada do meu codigo de novato...  rsrs

Comment: Com esse código aí não pode colocar nenhum caractere que não seja zero e um (nem mesmo quebras de linha). Atualizei o da resposta com uma proteção para esses casos, e um tipo que suporta até 4 bytes. Mas o algoritmo do original tá certinho também.

Comment: bacana!   to estudando! :D !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No SOzão tem esse código bem simples:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main()
{
    int bin, dec = 0, i;
    printf("\nEnter A Binary Number: \t");
    scanf("%d", &bin);
    for(i = 0; bin > 0; i++)
    {
        dec = dec + pow(2, i) * (bin % 10);
        bin = bin / 10;
    }
    printf("\nDecimal Equivalent of Binary Number: \t %d\n", dec);
    return 0;
}
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/i0n9s9)**.

O mesmo código, adaptado para ler de *strings*, para você testar com números maiores:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>

int main()
{
    char bin[100];
    unsigned long dec = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int s;
    fgets( bin, sizeof(bin), stdin);
    s = strlen( bin );
    while( s-- ) {
        if( bin[s] == '0' || bin[s] == '1' ) {
            dec = dec + pow(2, i++) * (bin[s] - '0');
        }
    };
    printf("\nDecimal Equivalent of Binary Number: \t %u\n", dec);
    return 0;
}
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/pE8ZLL)**.

Original:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/39218420/916193

Answer (score 5):

## A melhor maneira

A melhor maneira é criando um código que faça isso. C tem só o básico. C não é C# ou Java.

Dá pra procurar uma biblioteca que faça isso, mas não existe nada que todo mundo usa e seja considerado como "quase oficial". É muito comum que programadores C criem sua própria biblioteca para essas coisas e deixe só problemas complexos para bibliotecas.

## Representação

Note que as pessoas costumam confundir dado com representação do dado. O número é o número. Você não vê o número, ele só existe. O que você vê é uma representação. E para ver, certamente é um texto (*string*) com dígitos numéricos.

Então se tiver um número que na memória equivale ao que conhecemos como ao 129 para mostrar na tela vamos ter que achar o **caractere** `1`, depois o `2` e depois o `9`. Assim como se formos mostrar em binário acharemos um texto `10000001`. E hexadecimal `81`. Obviamente que uma representação pode ser armazenada também. Mas é sempre texto. O segredo é achar os caracteres corretos. Se faz isso com pura matemática. Alias, quem tem entendimento matemático adequado produz algoritmos simples para problemas simples. E não estou falando de decorar fórmulas. Na verdade quem faz isso não aprende resolver problemas.

Eu considero um erro trabalhar com valores numéricos para representar dados, mas vejo muitos exercícios assim.

## Algoritmo

O exercício comum de fazer isso é ótimo para desenvolver habilidade de produzir bons algoritmos.

A melhor solução passa por ir dividindo ou multiplicando o número pela base. Exemplo:

Se você tem um número binário, como calcula ele para decimal? Da direita para esquerda ele valerá sempre 0 ou um valor, quando aparecer 1, de acordo com a posição, igual é o decimal.

Olhemos o decimal que estamos acostumados. Começamos pela direita que é o valor menos significativo. Poderia começar pela esquerda, mas aí teria que calcular quantos dígitos tem antes de começar.

Então o último dígito vale o que seu valor mesmo. Genericamente falando é o valor dele vezes 10 (a base) elevado à posição. No caso a posição é zero (lembre-se que começamos sempre do zero). Quando dava aulas eu tinha vontade de chorar quando os alunos não sabiam que 10 elevando a zero é 1. Os professores de matemática costumam dizer que é convenção. Mas esse exercício ajuda entender porque é essa "convenção". O resultado é armazenado em algum lugar. No papel ou na memória do computador, depende de onde está fazendo o algoritmo. Se o dígito era 5, então temos 5 como resultado.

Depois vamos para o próximo dígito. Novamente é seu valor multiplicado pela base elevada à posição. Agora a posição é 1. Então 10^1 é 10. Então se o dígito era 3, então temos 30 como resultado.

A seguir usamos o dígito 6 (por exemplo) vezes 10 elevado a 2 (próxima posição. Então dá 600.

Para fazer o contrário trocamos a multiplicação pela divisão.

Se só tinha esses dígitos, somamos tudo e dá 635. É assim que um `printf()` ou um `toString()` (a função de formatação na verdade) em outras linguagens fazem para transformar o número em representação, ou pegar a representação e gerar um número (*parsing*, o que o `scanf()` costuma fazer).

O binário só muda a base, o algoritmo é o mesmo. Então vamos lá:

0011 1011 0101 da direita para a esquerda:

```
1 X 2^0 (1) = 1
0 X 2^1 (2) = 0
1 X 2^2 (4) = 4
0 X 2^3 (8) = 0
1 X 2^4 (16) = 16
1 X 2^5 (32) = 32
0 X 2^6 (64) = 0
1 X 2^7 (128) = 128
1 X 2^8 (256) = 256
1 X 2^9 (512) = 512
```

Soma tudo 949.

Agora pega 949 e faz ao contrário:

```
949 % 2 = 1 -> 949 / 2 = 474
474 % 2 = 0 -> 474 / 2 = 237
237 % 2 = 1 -> 237 / 2 = 118
118 % 2 = 0 -> 118 / 2 = 59
59 % 2 = 1 -> 59 / 2 = 29
29 % 2 = 1 -> 29 / 2 = 14
14 % 2 = 0 -> 14 / 2 = 7
7 % 2 = 1 -> 7 / 2 = 3
3 % 2 = 1 -> 3 / 2 = 1
1 % 2 = 1 -> 1 / 2 = 0
```

Junta todos os restos ao contrário: 1110110101

[Para hexadecimal a base é 16, mas o algoritmo é o mesmo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13576/101), tanto de um lado quanto outro. Dá para converter até mesmo de binário para hexadecimal e vice-versa, tudo direto sem passar pelo decimal.

Basicamente é isso. Agora é só codificar. Ou pegar pronto.

## Conclusão

O problema é comum: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D+bin%C3%A1rio+decimal Fazer enorme é opcional. O problema é simples e exige uma solução simples, e curta. Só aqui no site já foi perguntado várias vezes.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: valeu!  pra gente que ta começando, saber desse tipo de informação eh tudo o que faltou na escola!  obrigado!