# Ajuda com programa básico em C da aula de introdução à programação

Tags: c, loop

O exercício pede um programa que leia um número binário em forma de vetor de 'char' do teclado e retorne o seu correspondente em base 10. Eu escrevi um código mas os valores que ele retorna estão errados, alguém pode me dizer o motivo?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  int expon(int a, int x){
    int i, um;
    um = 1;
    for(i=0; i<x;i++){
      um = um * a;
    };
  return um;
  }


  char number[1024];
  scanf("%s", number);
  int i;
  int n = strlen(number) - 1;
  int novo = 0;
  for(i=0; i<n+1; i++){
    novo = novo + (number[i] * expon(2, n-i));
  }

  printf("%d", novo);

}
```

Also, acho que umas dicas de como deixar o meu código mais legível não cairiam mal hehehe

Comment: Tem coisa muito errada ai. Tu da declarando uma função dentro do `main()`. Olha, recomendo mais uma estudada pq ta faltando conhecimento básico aí, assim fica difícil de ajudar.

Comment: Além do que disse Shinforinpola note que number é um vetor de char mas em sua conta você não quer tratar a representação numérica dos caracteres mas sim o valor 0 ou 1 (o caractere '0' corresponde ao decimal 48). Faça: novo += ((number[i] - '0') * expon(2, n-i));

Comment: Use o #include <string.h> para o 'strlen' ser usado e em princípio ficará a funcionar

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como converter binário em decimal?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/152947/como-converter-bin%c3%a1rio-em-decimal)

Answer (score 2):

O seu principal problema é que `number[i]` vai conter o valor 48 para o `0` e o 49 para o `1`. A razão disso é que na tabela ASCII, esses são os códigos para os caracteres que representam o `0` e o `1`. Logo, você deve subtrair 48 (ou subtrair `'0'`) para converter o caractere no número.

Há outros problemas secundários também:

- A função de exponenciação dentro do `main` e não fora.
- `scanf` com `%s` sem limite, se comportando que nem o `gets`.
- A função de exponenciação pode ser substituída por um *shift-left*.
- `novo = novo + blablabla` pode ser simplificado para `novo += blablabla`.
- Você usa um `-1` na hora de atribuir a `n` para então usar um `+1` no `for`.

Seu código fica assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char number[1024];
    scanf("%1023s", number);
    int n = strlen(number);
    int novo = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        novo += ((number[i] - '0') * (1 << (n - i - 1)));
    }

    printf("%d", novo);
}
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no IDEONE.**](https://ideone.com/NnCHAu)

Answer (score 0):

Opa Cristus..

ta meio difícil de entender, recomendo que você revise mais o conceito básico, e pense melhor na lógica...

porem veja esse exemplo básico que converte um numero binário em decimal:

```
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<math.h>

    int main(){

    int bin, dec = 0, i;

    printf("\nEntre com o numero binario: ");
    scanf("%d", &bin);

    for(i = 0; bin > 0; i++){
        dec = dec + pow(2, i) * (bin % 10);
        bin = bin / 10;
    }
    printf("\nNumero convertido em Decimal: %d\n", dec);
    return 0;
 }
```