# Aparecem números aleatórios depois em algoritmo de ordenação

Tags: c, array, classificação

No final do meu programa o resultado está dando números aleatórios, o que ocorre?

```
main(){

    int i;
    int a[10];
    int x;
    int aux;

    for (i=0; i<10; i++){
    printf ("Entre com os numeros %i: ", i);
    scanf ("%i", & a[10]);
    }

for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    for (x=0; x<10; x++)
        if (a[i]>a[x+1]){

        aux = a[i];
        a[i] = a[i+1];
        a[i+1] = aux;

    }
}
printf ("Lista dos elementos em ordem a seguir:\n   ");

for (i = 0 ; i < 10; i++)
printf ("%i\n", a[i]);
}
```

Comment: Creio que o laço mais interno deva partir de i+1 e não de 0. A troca não deveria se entre a[i] e a[x], no seu programa a[x+1]? Creio que você misturou dois métodos de ordenação.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 4):

Tem vários problemas no código. O principal deles é que está dando um `scanf()` no elemento 10 do *array*, que nem é um elemento que existe dentro dele, e pega lixo na memória. Ele vai do 0 ao 9. E justamente por isso você deveria ter usado `i` ali e não `10`.

Mas o laço também está errado, o interno deveria começar de onde ele está no externo, ou seja, do `i + 1`, e não do 0 como foi colocado. Além disso a troca deve ser com o elemento `x` e não com o `i + 1`.

Eu mexi bem no código para ficar mais legível e usar algumas coisas melhores como [preferir o `%d` no lugar de `%i`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/152399/101).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int a[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("Entre com os numeros %d: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int x = i + 1; x < 10; x++) {
            if (a[i] > a[x]) {
                int aux = a[i];
                a[i] = a[x];
                a[x] = aux;
            }
        }
    }
    printf ("Lista dos elementos em ordem a seguir:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) printf("%d\n", a[i]);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/NUsMu8). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/rdotqghc-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/Sorting.c).

Answer (score 0):

acontece que você sempre está guardando o valor na ultima casa do vetor por um erro na leitura:

```
scanf ("%i", & a[10]);
```

ele deveria ser:

```
scanf ("%i", & a[i]);
```

Onde o contador do laço indique a posição do vetor a guardar o valor digitado.

**De onde vêm os números loucos?**

Então os números loucos que estão aparecendo na verdade são os restos de memórias de outros programas (que podem estar em execução ou não, então preste atenção nisso, porque desalocar um espaço de memória errado pode desligar o teu pc ou causar mal funcionamento de outro software em execução).

Reescrevi o código que você mandou de forma que vai funcionar, dá uma estudada nele:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){

  int i;
  int a[10];
  int x;
  int aux;

  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
      printf ("Entre com os numeros %i: ", i);
      scanf ("%i", &a[i]);
    }

  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
      for (x = 0; x < 10; x++){
            if (a[i] > a[x + 1]){
                aux = a[i];
                a[i] = a[i + 1];
                a[i + 1] = aux;
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        printf ("Valor escrito: %i\n", a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!!

Comment: Disponha, amigo!