# porque o resultado de minha operação ao ser imprimida está imprimindo 00 e não o resultado real?

Tags: c

Estou praticando sintaxe em linguagem C,um código sobre votação, escrevi um trecho do código e fui compilar pra testar,mas deu erro, quebrei a cabeça aqui e não soluciona, fiz um `casting`, e não deu certo, tipei com `int`, `double`, `float` e nada,`%d`,`%f` `%i` e nada...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<locale.h>

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"portuguese");

    double totalv=0, vnulos=0,vbrancos=0,vvalidos=0;
    double v,n,b;

    printf("digite a quantidade de votos brancos\n");
    scanf("%d",&vbrancos);
    printf("digite a quantidade de votos nulos\n");
    scanf("%d",&vnulos);
    printf("digite a quantidade de votos válidos\n\n");
    scanf("%d",&vvalidos);
    totalv=vbrancos+vnulos+vvalidos;

    if(vnulos>0){
        n=(vnulos/totalv)*100;
        printf(" foram um total de %.2d de votos nulos totalizando um percentual de %d %%",vnulos,n);

    }else{
        printf("valor incompatível\n tente novamente\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que o seu erro foi mudar os tipos das variáveis e não mudar os especificadores de conversão do `printf` e do `scanf`

Veja o seu código funcionando corretamente:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<locale.h>

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"portuguese");

    float totalv=0, vnulos=0,vbrancos=0,vvalidos=0;
    float v,n,b;

    printf("digite a quantidade de votos brancos\n");
    scanf("%f",&vbrancos);

    printf("digite a quantidade de votos nulos\n");
    scanf("%f",&vnulos);

    printf("digite a quantidade de votos válidos\n");
    scanf("%f",&vvalidos);

    totalv=vbrancos+vnulos+vvalidos;

    if(vnulos>0){
        n=(vnulos/totalv)*100;
        printf("votos total %f \n", totalv);
        printf(" foram um total de %.2f de votos nulos totalizando um percentual de %f %%",vnulos,n);

    }else{
        printf("valor incompatível\n tente novamente\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/9GPu05).

Correções no seu código:

Mudei suas variáveis para tipo `float`, devido a utilização da porcentagem. Observe no `printf` e no `scanf` que os especificadores de conversão foram alterados para `%f`.

Entretanto, não se limite a copiar o código.

Recomendo a leitura:

[Como ler do stdin em C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42981/como-ler-do-stdin-em-c)

[Diferença entre %i e %d](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/152399/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-i-e-d)

[Sintaxe de especificação de formato](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/cpp/c-runtime-library/format-specification-syntax-printf-and-wprintf-functions?view=vs-2019)

Comment: eu tinha mudado as variáveis , mas acredito te pecado em esquecer algum especificador, fiz agora como você sugeriu e realmente deu certo, eu conclui o código e ficou assim:

Comment: @crisman acredtio que foi isso mesmo. precisando de algum ajuda é só perguntar! Ou reabrir outras perguntas, não se esqueça de elaborar um [Exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) que demonstre o problema que está passando