# Calculadora não está capturando o segundo número

Tags: c, algoritmo, scanf

Estou com um código que eu escrevi, ele pega dois números e soma, subtrai, multiplica e divide. Porém, ao incrementar as perguntas no código e depois executar ele lê somente o número da primeira pergunta.

Onde estou errando? Visto que aparentemente o código não apresenta erro nenhum.

#### erro ao compilar:

[image: código compilado,numero 2 não é requisitado]

**segue o código:**

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
int main()
{

setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
printf("===============\n");
printf("CALCULADORA 1.0");
printf("\n===============\n");

  int num1, num2, soma, subtracao, multi, div;

  soma = num1 + num2;
  subtracao = num1-num2;
  multi = num1 * num2;
  div = num1 / num2;

  printf("Digite Dois Números a serem calculados:\n");
  printf("Primeiro Número:\n");

  scanf("Primeiro Número:%i\n",&num1);

  printf("Segundo Número:\n");
  scanf("Segundo Número:%i\n",&num2);
  printf("A soma é :%i\n",soma);
  printf("A subtração é : %i \n",subtracao);
  printf("O produto é:%i \n",multi);
  printf("A divisão é :%i \n",div);

}
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 2):

O maior problema é que você está colocando o texto no formatador do `scanf()`, ali é só para ter um padrão de entrada de dados e não um texto, inclusive porque o texto já estava escrito.

Tem outros problemas. As operações estão sendo realizadas antes do dado ser lido então os cálculos ocorrerão com dados já existentes na memória, até porque você não inicializou as variáveis. Pra falar a verdade a maioria das variáveis nem deveriam existir.

Melhorei outras coisas, preste atenção em cada detalhe do código e tirei coisas desnecessárias, pelo menos para o código atual. Ficou bem mais simples, não?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("===============\n");
    printf("CALCULADORA 1.0");
    printf("\n===============\n");
    printf("Digite Dois Números a serem calculados:\n");
    printf("Primeiro Número: ");
    int num1, num2;
    scanf("%d", &num1);
    printf("\nSegundo Número: ");
    scanf("%d", &num2);
    printf("\nA soma é: %d\n", num1 + num2);
    printf("A subtração é: %d\n", num1 - num2);
    printf("O produto é: %d\n", num1 * num2);
    printf("A divisão é: %d\n", num1 / num2);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/pNXCkT). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/ScanfArgumentc). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Console/ScanfArgument.c).

Comment: Obrigado pelo seu tempo e pela sua ajuda Maniero.
Percebi que você utilizou(%d) ao invéz de (%i).
Não preciso utilizar obrigatoriamente o %i então?já que o %d também abrange o conteúdo de %i?! De que forma eu posso estar inserindo  texto?(talvez eu deva estudar mais para descobrir,comecei estudar ontem de ontem sabe?!
Muito Obrigado novamente,Deus te abençoe!
Boa tarde!

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/152401/101. Já está tudo certo aí, não precisa fazer mais nada, siga o fluxo linha por linha.

Comment: @Bruno Poggian você poderia marca a resposta como aceita? Ajudaria a comunidade a não entrar na pergunta já que ela está respondida.