# Leitura de string com dois nomes ou mais

Tags: c, string, array

Como faço para ler uma string com um nome composto por exemplo: "Vitor Martins"? estou fazendo esse programa que armazena nome e nota de um aluno porém ele da um bug quando digita dois nomes.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>

    #define alunos 3

int main(){
int x;
float nota[alunos];
char nome[15];

for(x=0; x<alunos; x++){
    printf("Digite o nome do %d(o) aluno: ", x+1);
    scanf("%s", nome);

    printf("Digite a nota do aluno %s: ", nome);
    scanf("%f", &nota[x]);

    printf("\n");
}
```

}

Comment: leia isso: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42981/101. Provavelmente essa pergunta é duplicata se não desta de alguma outra, esse problema é recorrente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A regra geral é: não tente fazer nada complicado com scanf.

O objetivo da função scanf é trabalhar com dados estruturados, normalmente lidos de um arquivo.

Para trabalhar com leitura interativa de dados normalmente é preciso utilizar uma biblioteca, como a "ncurses" no Linux, ou então fazer a análise de cada linha "manualmente", o que é trabalhoso.

Nunca vi um programa "na vida real" que usa scanf, só em exemplos e exercícios escolares. :)

Dito tudo isso, dá pra fazer alguma coisa, como no exemplo abaixo, mas acho que não compensa o trabalho, sempre vai acabar ficando "meia boca". :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N_ALUNOS 3

static void ignoreRestOfLine(void)
{
   char c;
   while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
        /* discard */ ;
}

int main()
{
   int i;
   float nota[N_ALUNOS];
   char nome[15];

   for (i = 0; i < N_ALUNOS; i++)
   {
      printf("Digite o nome do %d(o) aluno: ", i+1);
      scanf("%14[ .a-zA-Z]%*[^\n]\n", nome);

      printf("Digite a nota do aluno %s: ", nome);
      scanf("%f", &nota[i]);
      ignoreRestOfLine();

      printf("\n");
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

você pode usar:

```
fgets (nome, 15, stdin);
```

ou pode usar o scanf mesmo aplicando uma regex que ira eliminar um espaço, pois se recordo bem o scanf reconhece um espaço como uma possivel quebra de linha para encerrar sua leitura, exemplo:

```
scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", nome);
```

Comment: Continua dando o mesmo problema, quando for digitar os nomes dos outros alunos o programa pula pra nota e não deixa digitar o nome, somente a nota

Comment: Após realizar um scanf é bom limpar o buffer de entrada com **fflush(stdin)**, provavelemnte isso vai acabar com o seu problema de pular a leitura.

Comment: Cuidado! A função `fflush` só opera em *buffers* de saída e seu uso em um buffer de entrada (ex: `fflush(stdin)`) além de não ser recomendado, tem comportamento indefinido ([link - em inglês](http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?answer=1052863818&id=1043284351))

Answer (score -2):

Se não me engano, é possivel utilizar o numero de caracteres no `%s` que irá incluir o espaço como um caractere.
Ex:

```
scanf("%50[^\n]s", nome);
```

Isto permite até 50 caracteres na variavel (incluindo espaços) e finaliza ao pressionar <kbd>Enter</kbd> (utilizando `\n`).