# Problema com Struct e Função em C

Tags: c, funções, struct

Boa noite, estou com um problema no código que estou fazendo. Não sei se estou excluindo os valores corretamente(e substituindo pelo próximo). O erro está aparecendo na substituição pelo próximo e não sei se estou passando corretamente o x, que é o indice.

```
struct fichacarro {
char  fabricante[15];
char modelo[15];
char combustivel[10];
char cor[10];
char placa[10];
int ano;
int km;
float preco;
};

int inserir(struct fichacarro carro[], int *x){


printf("\nModelo: ");
fflush(stdin);
fgets(carro[*x].modelo, 15, stdin);
printf("Fabricante: ");
fflush(stdin);
fgets(carro[*x].fabricante, 15, stdin);
printf("Combustivel (alcool, gasolina ou diesel): ");
fflush(stdin);
fgets(carro[*x].combustivel, 10, stdin);
printf("Cor (branco, preto ou prata): ");
fflush(stdin);
fgets(carro[*x].cor, 10, stdin);
printf("Placa: ");
fflush(stdin);
fgets(carro[*x].placa, 10, stdin);
printf("Ano: ");
scanf("%d", &carro[*x].ano);
printf("Kilometros: ");
scanf("%d", &carro[*x].km);
printf("Preco: ");
scanf("%f", &carro[*x].preco);
*x=*x+1;
system("cls");

}
int excluir(struct fichacarro carro[], int *x){
int k, j;
printf("Digite o indice do carro que quer excluir: ");
scanf("%d", &k);
k=k-1;

if(k>*x || k<0)
    printf("Indice nao existe");
    else {
         j=k;
        while (j<*x){

            carro[j].modelo=carro[j+1].modelo;
            carro[j].fabricante=carro[j+1].fabricante;
            carro[j].combustivel=carro[j+1].combustivel;
            carro[j].cor=carro[j+1].cor;
            carro[j].placa=carro[j+1].placa;
            carro[j].ano=carro[j+1].ano;
            carro[j].km=carro[j+1].km;
            carro[j].preco=carro[j+1].preco;
            j=j+1;
            }
            *x=*x-1;
        }
}

int pesquisar(){


}
int main(){

struct fichacarro carro[49];
int n, x=0, y, cont;


printf("Numero de veiculos: ");
scanf("%d", &n);
system("cls");

for (cont=0;cont<n;cont++){

printf("----OPCOES DE ESCOLHA----\n\n");
printf("1 - Inserir veiculo\n");
printf("2 - Excluir veiculo\n");
printf("3 - Pesquisar veiculo\n");
printf("4 - Sair\n\n");
printf("Opcao escolhida: ");
scanf("%d", &y);


    switch (y){

    case 1:
    inserir(carro, &x);
    break;

    case 2:
    excluir(carro, &x);
    break;

    case 3:
    pesquisar();
    break;

    case 4:
    x=n;
    break;

    }
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Usar `scanf("%c", &carro[x].placa);` vai ler só um único caractere. Acho que você quer ler uma string, ou seja `fgets(carro[x].placa, 10, stdin);`

Comment: ou usar gets(carro[x].placa); ? mas o problema aconteceu no numero real, tem alguma coisa fora do padrão na struct?

Comment: Não use a função `gets` nunca! Ela é odiada e considerada obsoleta por um bom motivo: o *buffer overflow*. E no seu caso, é muito fácil causar um problema desses, basta digitar mais de 10 caracteres para ele sair corrompendo a memória do seu programa e causando possíveis *segmentation fault*s. Use o `fgets(carro[x].placa, 10, stdin);` para já fazer certo desde o começo e evitar dores-de-cabeça futuras.

Comment: Vejo que se você não começar inserindo os dados quando o `x` for zero, não haveria outra oportunidade de fazê-lo antes de o programa acabar, uma vez que ele faz `printf("%.2f", carro[0].preco);` ao invés de `printf("%.2f", carro[x].preco);`.

Comment: Então substituir o 0 por x e colocar o fgets? não tem erro na passagem do vetor para a função?

Comment: Não sei se há mais algum erro. Mas trocar o 0 por x e colocar o fgets deve ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem (pelo menos) 2 erros.

O primeiro é o uso de "%c" quando deveria ser "%s".

O segundo é a declaração da estrutura:

```
struct FichaCarro
{
   char fabricante[15];
   char modelo[15];
   char combustivel[10];
   char cor[10];
   char placa[10];
   int ano[10];
   int km[15];
   float preco; // era "float preco[15]"
};
```

Comment: Pensei que podia usar todas as variáveis no mesmo char e pensei que podia ser o c e não s na leitura. Obrigado cara, me ajudou bastante, deu certo aqui.

Answer (score 4):

Na declaração da struct apresentada, os dados `ano`, `km` e `preco` são vetores e não apenas um dado como acho que deveria ser. Para simplificar a declaração ficaria assim:

```
struct fichacarro 
{

    char   fabricante[15]; 
    char   modelo[15]; 
    char   combustivel[10]; 
    char   cor[10];
    char   placa[10];
    int    ano;
    int    km;
    float  preco;

};
```

Para ler as strings na função `inserir` opite por usar a função `fgets` ([Leitura sugerida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42981/como-ler-do-stdin-em-c)).

```
printf("Modelo: ");
fgets(carro[x].modelo, 15, stdin);
fflush(stdin);
printf("\nFabricante: ");
fgets(carro[x].fabricante, 15, stdin);
fflush(stdin);
printf("\nCombustivel: ");
fgets(carro[x].combustivel, 10, stdin);
fflush(stdin);
printf("\nCor: ");
fgets(carro[x].cor, 10, stdin);
fflush(stdin);
printf("\nPlaca: ");
fgets(carro[x].placa, 10, stdin);
```

Uma dica no final do código no momento do teste, o indice deve ser o valor inserido `x` para confirmar se tudo esta realmente funcionando

```
printf("%.2f\n", carro[x].preco);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado cara, deu certo, estava com dúvidas ainda sobre struct e string, mas agora deu pra entender bem.

Comment: É sempre bom ajudar. @YgorFraga caso minha resposta tenha te ajudado a encontrar a solução, marque em aceitar resposta.

Comment: Certo, fiz isso, posso te fazer outra pergunta? Está dando um erro na exclusão dos dados. Vou editar e colocar o código atual, pode ver a parte da remoção?

Comment: Para atribuir uma string a outra não faça apenas `string1 = string2`. Ao invés disso use a função `strcpy() ` da biblioteca `string.h`. Como você está pegando qual carro está sendo excluido dentro da função, a variável x não precisa ser passada como parametro. Veja um exemplo: https://ideone.com/N7x85C

Comment: Certo, vou usar, mas na parte dos inteiros e do real está certo? usei certo o x e a questão do ponteiro?

Comment: Os inteiros e o real está sim. O `x` aparentemente está correto também. Caso não esteja dando certo, faça outra pergunta mostrando a função `excluir` , e como está utilizando ela.

Comment: Certo, deu tudo certo, fiquei com um problema na função pesquisar, pode dar uma verificada? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/156130/problema-com-pesquisa-com-struct