# Problema com pesquisa com Struct

Tags: c, funções, struct

No meu código, eu consigo inserir e excluir normalmente, porém nas pesquisas ele não printa, qual pode ser o problema? Pensei que daria certo da forma que fiz. Estou fazendo o 'if' corretamente?

```
struct fichacarro {
char  fabricante[15];
char modelo[15];
char combustivel[10];
char cor[10];
char placa[10];
int ano;
int km;
float preco;
};

int inserir(struct fichacarro carro[], int *x, int *f){





printf("\nModelo: ");
fflush(stdin);
fgets(carro[*x].modelo, 15, stdin);
printf("Fabricante: ");
fflush(stdin);
fgets(carro[*x].fabricante, 15, stdin);
printf("Combustivel (alcool, gasolina ou diesel): ");
fflush(stdin);
fgets(carro[*x].combustivel, 10, stdin);
printf("Cor (branco, preto ou prata): ");
fflush(stdin);
fgets(carro[*x].cor, 10, stdin);
printf("Placa: ");
fflush(stdin);
fgets(carro[*x].placa, 10, stdin);
printf("Ano: ");
scanf("%d", &carro[*x].ano);
printf("Kilometros: ");
scanf("%d", &carro[*x].km);
printf("Preco: ");
scanf("%f", &carro[*x].preco);
*x=*x+1;
*f=*f+1;
system("cls");

}
int excluir(struct fichacarro carro[], int *x, int *f){
    int k, j;
    printf("Digite o indice do carro que quer excluir: ");
    scanf("%d", &k);
    k=k-1;

    if(k>*x || k<0)
        printf("Indice nao existe");
        else {
         j=k;
            while (j<*x){
                strcpy(carro[j].modelo, carro[j+1].modelo);
                strcpy(carro[j].fabricante, carro[j+1].fabricante);
                strcpy(carro[j].combustivel, carro[j+1].combustivel);
                strcpy(carro[j].cor, carro[j+1].cor);
                strcpy(carro[j].placa, carro[j+1].placa);
                carro[j].ano=carro[j+1].ano;
                carro[j].km=carro[j+1].km;
                carro[j].preco=carro[j+1].preco;
                j=j+1;
                }
                *x=*x-1;
                *f=*f-1;
            }
    }

int pesquisar(struct fichacarro carro[], int *x, int f){
    int y, j;
    char cor[10];
    float preco;

    char fabricante[15];
    printf("\n----OPCOES DE PESQUISA----\n");
    printf("1 - Ler o nome do fabricante e informar todos os veiculos deste         fabricante.\n");
    printf("2 - Pesquisar os dados de veículos com o preço dentro de um limite fornecido.\n");
    printf("3 - Informar todos os veículos de determinada cor pesquisada\n\n");
    printf("Opcao escolhida: ");
    scanf("%d", &y);

        switch (y){

            case 1:
                printf("\nDigite o nome do fabricante: ");
                fflush(stdin);
                fgets(fabricante, 15, stdin);
                j=*x;

                while (j<f){
                    if(strcmp (fabricante, carro[j].fabricante) == 0 );{
                        printf("\nCarro: %d", j);
                        printf("\nModelo: %s\n", carro[j].modelo);
                    }
                    j=j+1;
                }
                system("pause");
                system("cls");
                break;

            case 2:
            printf("Preco limite: ");
            scanf("%f", &preco);
            j=*x;
             while (j<f){
                if (carro[j].preco<=preco);{
                    printf("\nCarro: %d", j);
                    printf("\nModelo: %s", carro[j].modelo);
                    printf("\nFabricante: %s", carro[j].fabricante);
                    printf("\nCombustivel: %s", carro[j].combustivel);
                    printf("\nCor: %s", carro[j].cor);
                    printf("\nPlaca: %s", carro[j].placa);
                    printf("\nAno: %d", carro[j].ano);
                    printf("\nKm: %d", carro[j].km);
                    printf("\nPreco: %f\n", carro[j].preco);

                }
                j=j+1;
             }
            system("pause");
            system("cls");
            break;

        case 3:
            printf("Cor: ");
            fflush(stdin);
            fgets(cor, 10, stdin);
            j=*x;
             while (j<f){
                if (carro[j].cor==cor);{
                    printf("\nCarro: %d", j);
                    printf("\nModelo: %s\n", carro[j].modelo);
                }
                j=j+1;
             }
            system("pause");
            system("cls");
            break;

        default:
        system("cls");
        printf("Nao encontrado.\n\n");
        system("pause");
        system("cls");
        break;
    }

}

int main(){

struct fichacarro carro[49];
int n, x=0, y, cont, f=0;


printf("Numero de acoes: ");
scanf("%d", &n);
system("cls");

for (cont=0;cont<n;cont++){

    printf("----OPCOES DE ESCOLHA----\n\n");
    printf("1 - Inserir veiculo\n");
    printf("2 - Excluir veiculo\n");
    printf("3 - Pesquisar veiculo\n");
    printf("4 - Sair\n\n");
    printf("Opcao escolhida: ");
    scanf("%d", &y);


    switch (y){

    case 1:
        inserir(carro, &x, &f);
        break;

    case 2:
        excluir(carro, &x, &f);
        break;

    case 3:
        pesquisar(carro, &x, f);
        break;

    case 4:
        x=n;
        break;

    default:
        system("cls");
        printf("Nao encontrado.\n\n");
        system("pause");
        system("cls");
        break;

    }
}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apesar de não estar claro qual é o objetivo das variáveis `x` e `f`analisando o código elas não diferem de valor em nenhum momento. Iniciam com valor `0` na função `main`, são incrementadas juntas na função `inserir` e decrementadas juntas na função `excluir`.
Dito isto, na função `pesquisar` a lista de carros é iterado de `x`a `f`, e por possuirem valores iguais impossibilita a entrada no laço de pesquisa `while(j<f)`.