# Qual o melhor a usar, scanf() ou get_s()?

Tags: c, string, scanf, entrada-de-dados

Tendo o nome 'Maria da silva' como exemplo:

`scanf()` apenas vai ler Maria, `get_s()` vai ler ela toda, correto?

Estou na dúvida do melhor a se utilizar, meu professor da faculdade diz que devemos limpar o *buffer* para o `scanf()` ler, afinal em C qual melhor opção para ler *strings* com intervalos de espaços?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pra falar a verdade nenhum. Em código real em produção quase todo mundo usa algo criado para ler porque tudo o que existe tem problemas. Isto corre com várias funções de C, e este é um dos problemas de uma linguagem que quer fornecer só o básico e não quer evoluir (ainda que isto tenha suas vantagens também).

Para exercícios e códigos simples depende do que quer. Mas já posso adiantar que elas coisa de limpar o *buffer* não faz sentido e quem sabe programar em C de verdade sabe disto. Existe um [mito de usar `fflush(stdin)`](http://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush.html). Até funciona em algum compilador (porque optaram por colocar isso na biblioteca padrão deles), mas isto não é C padrão, então não deve usar. A não ser que esteja programando em um dialeto do C. Mas se está aprendendo, aprenda certo.

O [`scanf()` em geral não é uma boa opção](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html) a não ser para o bem básico. Existem técnicas que ajudam em alguns problemas, mas não consegue controlar todas as situações. Pode usar para exercício rápido.

O `gets_s()` é muito mais simplista e só está disponível em compiladores C11 que é meio raro ter implementado. Se usar ele fica meio sem poder portar.

Não use nenhum dos dois, use `fgets()`. Esta função foi concebida para leituras mais complexas, mas mesmo ela não serve para tudo e pode ter problema com *buffer*. E ela é meio chatinha de usar, tem entender como vem os dados, eventualmente manipulá-lo, mas programar em C e não entender com profundidade o que está fazendo não dá certo.

Pelo menos não pensou no `gets()` que é inseguro, já é uma vantagem.

Veja também [Como ler do stdin em C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42981/101) onde mostra as opções.

Se você não se comprometer totalmente em aprender C é melhor nem tentar muito. Eu sou favorável a aprender C como forma de entender o que está ocorrendo, mas não acho que precisa aprender cada detalhe se não for trabalhar como programador C. Se for só para aprender programar e não o C em si, importa pouco qual usar, porque o que importa são outras coisas da linguagem. Se vai aprender a linguagem para uso no dia a dia então ambos são ruins.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: então não existe diferença entre gets_s e fgets? , apenas que o f para quando tiver \n?

Comment: @VitorGonçalves editei, veja se ajudou mais.

Comment: sim obrigado , por isso estou perguntando , não adianta só usar sem saber o motivo e podendo está usando um  melhor. Obrigado pela resposta!!.

Comment: Desculpa abrir novamente o tópico @maniero , mas procurei saber mais e encontrei scanf("%[^\n]s", variavel); (consigo utilizar ele sem problemas?)  , ainda preciso utilizar o scanf para não acabar embolando com a faculdade , mas já estou me inteirando sobre o fgets

Comment: Para exercícios, na maioria das vezes, sim, e em exercícios há um certo controle que permite seu uso.

Answer (score 0):

```
char nome[25];
scanf(" %24[^\n]s", nome);
```

Poderá fazer desta maneira, o mais importante é que limite o `scanf` como está nesse exemplo, caso retire o `24` e o utilizador insira um nome maior que 24 caracteres o programa vai dar bug.

Alem do mais o `scanf` dessa maneira irá limpar o `buffer` primeiro com aquele espaço antes do `%`.

---

Outra maneira seria usar o `fgets(nome, 24, stdin);` pois tambem limita o numero de caracteres a utilizar.

---

O `gets_s` irá fazer o mesmo que esses 2, por isso não vejo grandes vantagens, é importante é usar o `scanf` de maneira correta.

---

*Tente este pedaço de codigo:*

```
int main()
{
  int x;
  char nome[25];
  scanf("%d", &x);
  fgets(nome, 24, stdin);
  printf("%s", nome);
}
```

O que irá acontecer é que não irá ler o nome da pessoa, pois é preciso limpar o `buffer` depois de ler um `int`, neste caso o mais correto seria utilizar o `scanf` da maneira que fiz.

---

- Se não precisar de limpar o `buffer` primeiro então pode utilizar `fgets` ou `gets_s`, se precisar de limpar o `buffer` então é mais facil usar  `scanf` pois basta aquele `espaço` antes do `%` que resolve o problema.

Comment: então o melhor é usar gets_s ? , não sei se ainda tem o problema de eu limitar na char um vetor de 10 por exemplo e digitar 11 , ele ainda continua jogando 11 para o char?(como era com gets)

Comment: Com o gets_s tambem limita o numero de caracteres `char *gets_s( char *str, rsize_t n );` Eu usaria o `fgets` ou o `scanf` da maneira como fiz, é importante usar daquela maneira