# Problema com switch case dentro de for loop

Tags: c, for, switch

Preciso de ajuda com meu código com switch case dentro de for loop.

Sou iniciante em programação e não entendi o porque de o loop não ser executado como desejado. O desejado seria executar os printfs antes do switch e, posteriormente, o switch em si. Assim que a opção dentro do switch fosse escolhida e tudo dentro dela fosse executado, o loop começaria novamente. **Por algum motivo, ele recomeça mas os printfs antes do switch aparecem mais de uma vez (uma vez sendo o desejado)**.

Se alguém puder me dizer o que eu fiz de errado e o que eu posso fazer para consertar eu agradeceria.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  char opcao;//opcao=a vista ou parcelado
  float trans, soma;//transações, soma=soma das trans
  int numt;//número de trasações

  trans = 0;
  soma = 0;

    for(numt=0;numt<15;numt++)/* Este loop é feito duas vezes seguidas sem chance de interação após a primeira entrada de dados, por algum motivo */
    {
      printf("\nEscolha umas das duas opções:");
      printf("\nv = transações à vista");
      printf("\np = transações a prazo");
      printf("\nDigite a sua escolha: ");
      scanf("%c", &opcao);
    
      switch(opcao)
      {
        case'v':
        printf("\nDigite uma transação: ");
        scanf("%f", &trans);
        soma = soma + trans;
        break;

        case'p':
        printf("");
        printf("\nDigite uma transação: ");
        break;

        default:
        printf("\nERRO! A opção deve ser 'v' ou 'p'. Reinicie o programa.");
      }

    }  
    
    printf("\nO valor das compras à vista é: %.2f", soma);
    printf("\nO valor total das compras");

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema está na seguinte linha:

```
scanf("%c", &opcao);
```

O que acontece é que quando digitamos algum caractere no terminal, na prática é enviado para o buffer do teclado (*stdin*), dois caracteres:

1. O próprio caractere inserido.
2. O caractere `\n`, gerado ao pressionar a tecla *Enter*.

Como você está lendo apenas um caractere, o `\n` ainda está no buffer do teclado, sendo lido na segunda iteração do laço, pulando a segunda leitura do `scanf()` e caindo no *default* do seu `switch-case`, que imprime o erro.

Logo, ao terminar a leitura de qualquer dado do teclado, usando o `scanf()` ou comandos similares, o ideal é sempre limpar o *buffer* do teclado para retirar os "restos de dados" de dentro dele. Para isso, você pode colocar a função abaixo acima da sua função `main()`:

```
void flush_buffer(){
    int c;
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
    /* Descarta os demais caracteres do buffer */ ;
}
```

E chamá-la dentro da função `main()`, após cada `scanf()`, da forma abaixo:

```
  scanf("%c", &opcao);
  flush_buffer();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2979217

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/325635/101