# scanf(), gets() e fgets(). Qual a diferença?

Tags: c

Boa tarde a todos,

Estava estudando um pouco de algorítimos em C [especialmente *Strings*] e não pude deixar de notar que se usa `fgets()`e `scanf()` para leitura de strings frequentemente, mas raramente se usa o `gets()` [Que inclusive é acusado por alguns compiladores como 'não segura']. Gostaria, se possível, que algumas das minhas dúvidas fossem sanadas

- Qual a diferença entre os 3 em tempo de execução.
- Qual o motivo de se usar mais o `fgets()` que o `gets()` para strings.
- Porque o `gets()` é considerada uma função "não segura".
- `fgets()` ou `scanf()`, qual a mais apropriada pra o tratamento de strings?

Agradeço desde já pela atenção.

P.S: Se não ficou claro até aqui minha dúvida, favor sinalizar pra que eu possa corrigir.

Comment: Isso https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42981/101?

Comment: Exatamente isso, obrigado!