# Cadastro de cliente em C salvando dados em um arquivo.txt

Tags: c

Bom dia galera, estou tentando aprender a linguagem C, e estou fazendo um programa para cadastrar clientes sem usar um banco de dados,preciso salvar os dados (como nome, endereco, telefone, email e senha), em um arquivo.txt, meu código esta assim até agora:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    FILE * pFile;
    int n;
    char nome[50];
    char endereco[150];
    char telefone[12];
    char email[100];
    char senha[20];

   pFile = fopen ("myfile.txt","a");
   for (n=0 ; n<6 ; n++)
   {
     if(n == 0){
        puts ("Digite seu nome: ");
        gets (nome);
        fprintf (pFile, "Nome %d [%-100.100s]\n",nome);
        n++;
     }
     if(n == 1){
         puts ("Digite seu endereco: ");
         gets (endereco);
         fprintf (pFile, "Endereco %d [%-100.100s]\n",endereco);
         n++;
     }
     if(n == 2){
         puts ("Digite seu telefone: ");
         gets (telefone);
         fprintf (pFile, "Telefone %d [%-10.10s]\n",telefone);
         n++;
     }
     if(n == 3){
         puts ("Digite seu email: ");
         gets (email);
         fprintf (pFile, "Email %d [%-100.10S0s]\n",email);
         n++;
     }
     if(n == 4){
         puts ("Digite sua senha: ");
         gets (senha);
         fprintf (pFile, "Senha %d [%-10.10s]\n",senha);
         n++;
     }
     if(n == 5){
         puts ("Cliente cadastrado com sucesso!");
         n++;
     }
   }
   fclose (pFile);

   return 0;
}
```

Dando uma pesquisada encontrei o fgets() mas nao entendi direito como usa-lo (e nem sei se realmente devo usa-lo). Sei que é uma coisa bem basica mas estou tendo bastante dificuldade, agradeço desde ja a ajuda!

Segundo o link que comentaram aqui consegui progredir no projeto, porem o programa nao esta salvando os dados realmente no 'myfile.txt' eles estão aparecendo assim:

> Nome 2686726 [MZ
>   ]
>
> Endereco 2686576 [MZ
>   ]
>
> Telefone 2686564 [MZ       ]
>
> Email 2686464 [Senha 2686444 [MZ       ]

Alguém teria alguma solução ou outro site que eu posso estar estudando mais sobre o assunto!

Comment: Relacionada: [Como ler do stdin em C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42981/7210)

Comment: Você deseja que em seu arquivo de saída os campos tenham tamanho fixo ou que exista algum caractere separador entre os campos? Seus comando scanf para strings estão errados. Veja aqui a descrição e exemplo de uso da função fprintf: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf/

Comment: não entendi muito bem a pergunta mas (pq realmente estou bem no começo) mas eu preciso que tenha espaço entre eles, pois será escrito o nome completo, endereço e etc, vou dar uma olha no site que vc mandou, muito obrigado

Comment: Em seus fprintf se você está imprimindo uma string (por exemplo: nome) por qual razão você coloca como especificação de formato o %d (que é o formato para números inteiros)? Idem para as demais strings. Tente colocar apenas o %s e, se for o caso, posteriormente você incrementa o formato para um layout mais adequado.

Comment: cara muito obrigado, como disse estou aprendendo C agora e nem me liguei no %d, troquei por %s e esta funcionando, o unico problema agora é que ele salva os dados e depois adiciona o "[MZ   ]" no final vc saberia como retirar isso ??

Comment: alias consegui aqui, muito obrigado novamente pela ajuda