# Calcular a quantidade de caracteres da maior palavra em um arquivo

Tags: c

O arquivo está escrito na seguinte forma:

```
palavra0palavra0palavra0
```

Sendo que as palavras são diferentes.
O problema é calcular o tamanho da maior palavra que aparece entre os zeros, sendo que o arquivo pode ter qualquer tamanho.

Estou travado no problema há dias. Pensei em calcular a quantidade de caracteres e colocá-los em uma string para depois comparar. O problema está sendo justamente comparar o tamanho das palavras entre os zeros para imprimir o maior.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
 
  char str[64];
  
  scanf("%64s", str);
 
  FILE *f= fopen(str, "r");

  if(!f){
    fprintf(stderr, "ERRO");
    return 1;
  }
  char c;

  //Calculo do tamanho do arq//
  fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
 long val1= ftell(f);
 fseek(f,0,SEEK_SET);//


  
 while((fscanf(f, "%c", &c)) != EOF){
   if(c=='0'){
     long y= ftell(f);
    
     
     printf("%ld", y);
     
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Seu código](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/458889/112052), apesar de "funcionar", não é o ideal, porque você está percorrendo o arquivo duas vezes, desnecessariamente.

Se as palavras estão separadas por zero, basta criar um contador para o tamanho da palavra atual, e ir incrementando até encontrar um zero. Quando um zero for encontrado, quer dizer que aquela palavra terminou, e aí você verifica se esse contador é o maior valor encontrado até então. Aí você zera o contador e inicia a contagem da próxima palavra.

Além disso, para mim não ficou claro se depois da última palavra sempre tem um zero ou não (seu código falha se não tiver zero no final e a maior palavra for a última, [veja aqui](https://repl.it/@hkotsubo/CrimsonTotalTranslation#main.c)).

Enfim, dá para fazer em um único *loop*:

```
FILE *f = fopen ("scores.txt", "r");
if (!f) {
    fprintf (stderr, "ERRO");
    return 1;
}

// tamanho da palavra atual e o maior tamanho encontrado
int tamanho = 0, maior = -1;
int c;
do {
    c = fgetc(f); // lê um caractere
    if (c == '0' || c == EOF) { // se for zero, ou terminou o arquivo, é porque terminou uma palavra
        if (tamanho > maior) // verifica se é maior
            maior = tamanho;
        tamanho = 0; // reinicia a contagem, para a próxima palavra
    } else { // não é zero nem o final do arquivo, aumenta o contador do tamanho da palavra
        tamanho++;
    }
} while (c != EOF);

printf("%d", maior);
```

Agora não só ele não precisa ler o arquivo duas vezes, como também funciona caso a última palavra não tenha o zero depois ([veja aqui](https://repl.it/@hkotsubo/LuminousVisibleAddresses#main.c) a diferença).

Também retirei o primeiro `scanf`, já que o valor lido (a variável `str`) não estava sendo usado para nada. E troquei `fscanf` por [`fgetc`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgetc/), cuja finalidade é ler um único caractere da *stream* de dados informada (veja mais detalhes [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42981/112052)).

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver, fica ai para quem quiser:

```
int
main (void)
{

  char str[64];


  scanf ("%64s", str);

  FILE *f = fopen ("scores.txt", "r");

  if (!f)
    {
      fprintf (stderr, "ERRO");
      return 1;
    }

  char c;
  int n = 0, i = 0, a, b, d;
  while (fscanf (f, "%c", &c) != EOF)
    {
      if (c == '0')
    {
      n++;
    }
    }

  int val[n];
  rewind (f);

  while (fscanf (f, "%c", &c) != EOF)
    {
      if (c == '0')
    {
      b = a;
      long y = ftell (f);
      a = y;
      d = a - b;
      val[i] = d - 1;
      i++;

    }
    }
  int Maior = val[0];
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
   if(Maior<val[i]){
   Maior=val[i];}}

   printf("%d", Maior);

    
  

  return 0;

}
```