# Tratamento de entrada com retorno do scanf()

Tags: c, console, scanf

Estou tentando escrever um tratamento de entrada no meu código em C no trecho em que os *n* valores de um vetor e são lidos. Caso dê algum erro na leitura (se a entrada for um `char` por exemplo), atribua 885444751 ao valor na posição do erro e siga para a próxima (por isso o `continue`). Entretanto, no primeiro valor inválido ele sai do for e pula para a próxima etapa do programa. Por que ele se comporta dessa forma?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
  
 int n, *valores, *sequencia, i, ret;
    ret = scanf("%d",&n);
    if(ret!=1)
      printf("0\n");
    else{
        valores = (int *)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
        sequencia = (int *)malloc(60*sizeof(int));
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
            if(scanf("%d", &valores[i])!=1){
                valores[i]=885444751;
                continue;
                
                
            }
        }
        printf("Pulei direto\n");
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Creio que você está pressupondo que quando ele encontra algo que não seja número ele pulará este algo não-numérico, o que não é verdade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema principal é que o *buffer* fica sujo e tem que limpá-lo. `scanf()` não é muito adequado para entrada de dados muito simples. De forma mais organizada fica assim (ainda que poderia ser melhorado):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int n;
    int ret = scanf("%d", &n);
    int *valores;
    if (ret != 1) {
        printf("0\n");
        return 1;
    } else {
        valores = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (scanf("%d", &valores[i]) != 1) valores[i] = 885444751;
            int c;
            while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {}
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) printf("%d\n", valores[i]);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/YSwwkH). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/rvtqjntu-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Console/ClearBuffer.c).

Comment: Qual seria a função mais adequada? getchar()?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42981/101