# Como ler com strings separadas por underline

Tags: c, scanf

```
for (i=0; i < n; i++){
    char NomeAluno[15];
    char Sobrenome[15];

    scanf("%s_%s", NomeAluno, Sobrenome);

    strcpy(A[i].Nome , NomeAluno);
    strcpy(A[i].Sobrenome , Sobrenome);
```

Para um número `N` de alunos entrará o nome e o sobrenome separados por `_` da seguinte maneira: `luis_marcos`.

Eu quero que o programa leia separadamente o nome e o sobrenome, só que não é isso que está acontecendo. O programa está me devolvendo o apenas o `NomeAluno` como sendo `luis_marcos`, e o sobrenome não está devolvendo nada. O quê estou fazendo errado nesse `scanf`?

Comment: Poderia ser `scanf("%[^_]_%s", NomeAluno, Sobrenome)` - o `[^_]` indica que é pra ler tudo exceto o `_`, e depois você lê o próprio `_` e por fim `%s` lê o restante. Claro que pode dar problema se o nome digitado for maior que o tamanho que vc alocou, e aí o melhor é usar `strtok` como indicado abaixo.

Comment: Complementando, é interessante ler [como ler do stdin em C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42981/112052)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A função `scanf` vai ler o que conseguir do buffer para atribuir a outras variáveis se os valores na entrada estiverem *separados por espaços*.

[Referência sobre a função scanf caso queira saber mais](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html). Há outras formas de ler entradas, definir quais caracteres são válidos e efetuar conversão de tipos.

Para fazer a leitura da forma que deseja, dado que `scanf` está lendo o valor e atribuindo-o a sua primeira variável, uma implementação para separar os valores pode ser feita utilizando a função `strtok`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char nome_sobrenome[30];
    char *nome;
    char *sobrenome;
    char separador[1] = "_";
    
    // Lemos o input da mesma forma.
    scanf("%s_%s", nome_sobrenome);

    // Não há problema algum se quiser inserir alguma validação
    // neste ponto do programa e parar sua execução caso a entrada
    // não seja válida.
    
    // Usamos a função "strtok" que funciona como um "split" em outras
    // linguagens de programação de alto nível, retornando um ponteiro para
    // a ocorrência encontrada.
    // Já sabemos que o input é de sempre duas palavras separadas por underscore,
    // então:
    nome = strtok(nome_sobrenome, separador);
    
    // Passando NULL como argumento nesta chamada para fazer com que a implementação de
    // "strtok" use o buffer que foi lido na primeira chamada (que ainda é
    // "luis_marcos").
    sobrenome = strtok(NULL, separador);

    // Escrevendo os nomes do buffer novamente, dessa vez separados por espaço
    // e com cada nome em uma variável diferente (ponteiros para cada valor).
    printf("%s %s", nome, sobrenome);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Se compilarmos o código acima e executarmos o programa passando o valor:

```
luis_marcos
```

Teremos o retorno:

```
luis marcos
```

[Esta resposta do Stack Overflow em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28931379/implementation-of-strtok-function/33272590#33272590) explica o funcionamento da função `strtok` mais a fundo, com referências.