# Encontrar o maior valor, posição e quantidade de numeros de um arquivo em C

Tags: c

sou novo aqui e novo em linguagem C.
Recebi um trabalho da faculdade que tem um exercício que pede o maior valor, a posição e a quantidade de numeros de um arquivo que contém números reais.
Pensei em passar cada string(numero) inscrito no arquivo .txt para um vetor, por exemplo array[0]=1, array[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WLqj.png)=2..., tentei por fgets, fscanf, mas não consegui, o único lugar que consegui achar algo que me ajudasse nisso foi em um site na gringa, porém o usuário decidiu mudar de linguagem que era bem mais fácil(C++), tenho que usar C, então decidi criar uma função para adicionar quebra de linhas para cada white space(para separar os numeros dos outros por linha), aí o programa ia ler cada linha e cada linha ia ser um valor para adicionar no array. Vi vídeos sobre write[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] de arquivos em C, mas ainda não consegui adicionar essas quebras de linha. Alguém poderia me ajudar a adicionar essas quebras de linha e ler para adicionar no array?
Não posso mexer no arquivo .txt por conta própria.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
    int i;
    char* v[32];
    char line[100];
    char junk[100];

    FILE *file = fopen("maiorR.txt", "r");
    if(file==NULL) {
        printf("Erro, não foi possível abrir o arquivo.");
        return 1;
    }
    while(!feof(file)) {
        fscanf(file,"%[^ \n\t\r]s",line); //Get text
        printf("%s\n", line);

        fscanf(file,"%[ \n\t\r]s",junk); //Remove any 'white space' characters
    }




    fclose(file);


  return(0);
}
```

até agora fiz isso, mas ele não tá quebrando linha no arquivo, só ta quebrando linha por fora.

```
15 

1.47 52.21 
1.50 53.12 
1.52 54.48 
1.55 55.84 
1.57 57.20 
1.60 58.57 
1.63 59.93 
1.65 61.29 
1.68 63.11 
1.70 64.47 
1.73 66.28 
1.75 68.10 
1.78 69.92 
1.80 72.19 
1.83 74.46 

1.76
```

este é o arquivo maiorR.txt

Comment: Não precisa dessa complicação toda. Como o arquivo é bem formado e só tem números, simplesmente leia-os com `fscanf` até que não tenha mais nenhum. E se só precisa saber qual o maior e a quantidade, não precisa guardar em um array (como fez a resposta abaixo). Enfim, seria algo do tipo: https://replit.com/@hkotsubo/Cmaiornumeroarquivo#main.c - E claro que para um exercício está OK, mas não deixe de ler [Como ler do stdin em C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42981/112052)

Answer (score -2):

a função **fscanf** lê uma sequência de caracteres até encontrar um espaço em branco ,  e depois converter essa string lida por fscanf em float com a função **atof** , assim  :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
float numerosDecimais[100];
while( fscanf(file,"%s",line) != EOF)   /// !feof(file)
{
    numerosDecimais[x] = atof(line);
    x++;
    printf("%3d %6s\n", x,line);
}
for(i=0; i<x; i++)
    printf("%7.2f\n",numerosDecimais[i]);;
```

o x terá a qtd de números no arquivo .