# Dúvida sobre a função strlen()?

Tags: c, string, funções

Question)

Ler uma string de no máximo 50 caracteres e criar uma nova string com seu inverso,
isso é a ultima letra da primeira string será a primeira na nova string e assim sucessivamente.

Doubt)

Eu conheço a lógica do programa, estou recebendo uma string, conhecendo o tamanho dela, e invertendo os caracteres nela através de um loop.

Para isso utilizei a função strlen(), testei ela sem o "-1" e o programa não imprimia nada, testei com o "-1" e o programa funcionou perfeitamente.

Segundo fontes da internet a função strlen() conta o tamanho da string sem o "\0" ou "NULL", seguindo essa lógica meu programa deveria funcionar perfeitamente sem o "-1", mas na prática aparentemente a função strlen() está me retornando o tamanho com o "\0" ou "NULL", sendo assim necessário utilizar o "-1".

Alguém poderia me explicar o por quê do meu programa não dar certo sem utilizar o "-1", e o por quê dele dar certo utilizando o "-1", se a função strlen(), retorna o tamanho sem o "\0" ou "NULL" ???

Code)

```
char string[51];
 printf("Write a phrase with maximum of 50 characters :");
 fflush(stdin);
 gets(string);

 printf("\nThe string is %s !!!\n",string);

 int size=strlen(string)-1;

 char stringV[51];
 int i, j=0;

 for(i=size; i>=0; i--){
     printf("%c ",string[i]);
     stringV[j]=string[i];
     j++;
 }

 printf("\n\nThe inverted string is %s !!!\n",stringV);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro vale lembrar que [strings em C na verdade são **arrays** de `char` terminados com `'\0'`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14709667).

E em um array, os índices começam em zero (a primeira posição é zero, a segunda é 1, a terceira é 2, etc).

Então se o tamanho da string for 4 (ou seja, se `strlen(string)` retornar 4), os índices que contém caracteres serão 0, 1, 2 e 3 - e no índice 4 estará o terminador de string (o `'\0'`). Por exemplo, se a string for `"abcd"`, temos o seguinte:

| Posição | caractere |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | `'a'` |
| 1 | `'b'` |
| 2 | `'c'` |
| 3 | `'d'` |
| 4 | `'\0'` |

Como a string tem 4 caracteres ("abcd"), `strlen(string)` retorna `4` (se `strlen` considerasse o `'\0'`, retornaria `5`).

E o que acontece se você começar o *loop* da posição 4? A posição zero de `stringV` será `'\0'`, o que indica que é uma string vazia. Não importa se ela tem outros caracteres depois, o primeiro `'\0'` que for encontrado determina que a string termina ali.

Por isso precisa subtrair 1 do resultado de `strlen(string)`, assim você garante que vai começar do último caractere da string (e não do `'\0'`).

Comment: Entendi, bacana ! Top ! O tamanho da string é 4, mas está armazenada de 0 a 3.

Comment: Muito obrigado !!

Comment: @LeandroSena Só pra complementar, [não use `gets`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42981/112052) e nem [`fflush(stdin)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2979209) - leia os links para entender os motivos (além de ver alternativas melhores). E também faltou colocar o terminador: depois do `for`, precisa fazer `stringV[j] = '\0';`

Comment: Por fim, também daria para fazer assim: `int size = strlen(string); for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { stringV[i] = string[size - i - 1]; } stringV[size] = '\0';`